# tombstones and beer mugs

Tags: symbols, theorems, fun

I'm trying to find an alternative to the standard tombstone qed symbol for more informal papers.
I initially thought of an empty square with Pub written inside, but what would actually be better would be a small beer mug symbol. (much like the one found in this set of icons http://dutchicon.com/iconsets/food-and-drinks-icons)

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to such a symbol in the comprehensive latex symbol list (although many funny symbols can be found there).
Has anyone thought about this? Is there any quick-and-dirty solution?

Comment: Use the beer mug unicode symbol  U+1F37A see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f37a/index.htm

Comment: ah, excellent. is there a quick way insert unicode characters in tex?

Comment: (without using xetex that is)

Comment: Not without a font! But you can create one using metapost! I would rather use a red tombstone mark, as in paint the town red:)

Comment: but isn't metapost evil? (when using pdftex/tikz)

Comment: @donkeykong: no, though you might need to specify a graphics rule for type mps, then pdflatex will handle MetaPOST just fine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I personally don't like the idea of the beer mug, but you could redefine `\qedsymbol` to use a previously saved image of a beer mug:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\raisebox{-4pt}{\includegraphics[height=10pt]{beer-mug}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Test proof of a really basic theorem.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Here's a nice vector graphics beer mug that's available under a CC license: http://thenounproject.com/noun/beer/#icon-No634

Comment: thanks to both Seamus and Gonzalo, that's probably the easiest way to do it.

Comment: @gonzalo: it's for an informal document, do you have an alternative to suggest?

Answer (score 8):

Would you settle for a `\Coffeecup` from the `marvosym` package instead?

Comment: coffee is the fuel for proving theorems, so after a proof you really need something different! :) but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

How about a smiley face? :) There are some both in the `wasysym` and the `marvosym` package. I guess everyone is happy, when he arrives at the end of a demonstration. ;)

Comment: depends on the proof...

Comment: related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3695/smileys-in-latex

Comment: ...and no smiley with a beer mug... that's sad... :P