# Christmas tree QED symbol

Tags: fun

I am looking to replace the \qed or \qedsymbol with a Christmas tree or a Christmas tree inside a box. I've done this already with a smiley by using \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\smiley}, but I don't know how one would go about this using a Christmas tree (since there is no Christmas tree character)

Comment: You could make use of `fontawesome5`'s `\faTree` symbol: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\faTree}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
Merry Christmas!
\end{proof}  
\end{document}` Resulting output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXraq.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to [tombstones and beer mugs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32026/tombstones-and-beer-mugs?rq=1)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}

\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\raisebox{-4pt}{\includegraphics[height=10pt]{christ_tree}}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{proof}
        Merry Christmas!
    \end{proof}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]