# Something between \frownie and \smiley

Tags: beamer, symbols

Inside a beamer presentation, I would like to compare and contrast several alternatives. For each, I would like to highlight the "pros" (with a `\item[\Large\smiley]`), the "cons" (with a `\item[\Large\frownie]`) and "neutral" observations. Is there a symbol with a face that is neither happy, nor sad, but rather neutral?

Comment: Related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3695/4012 -- possibly even a duplicate, if that question lists all the emoticons available in packages. I'm assuming though that someone will provide a TikZ answer here.

Comment: @doncherry Thanks for the comment. I was hoping for a solution without \includegraphics{}

Comment: looks at http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/emoticons/

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Here is a `tikz` version where you can use  `\Simley{<smile_level>}` and control the smile level (setting shown below in the image) with `1` begin very happy, to `-1` being very unhappy:

[image]

You can actually use larger numbers, but the results may not be desirable.  The `1.75` fudge factor in the code below was used so that the reasonable range is `-1...1` so you can adjust those as desired.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\Simley}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.11]
    \newcommand*{\SmileyRadius}{1.0}%
    \draw [fill=brown!10] (0,0) circle (\SmileyRadius)% outside circle
        %node [yshift=-0.22*\SmileyRadius cm] {\tiny #1}% uncomment this to see the smile factor
        ;  

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\eyeX}{0.5*\SmileyRadius*cos(30)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\eyeY}{0.5*\SmileyRadius*sin(30)}
    \draw [fill=cyan,draw=none] (\eyeX,\eyeY) circle (0.15cm);
    \draw [fill=cyan,draw=none] (-\eyeX,\eyeY) circle (0.15cm);

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xScale}{2*\eyeX/180}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yScale}{1.0*\eyeY}
    \draw[color=red, domain=-\eyeX:\eyeX]   
        plot ({\x},{
            -0.1+#1*0.15 % shift the smiley as smile decreases
            -#1*1.75*\yScale*(sin((\x+\eyeX)/\xScale))-\eyeY});
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}
  \Simley{1}
  \Simley{0.5}
  \Simley{0}
  \Simley{-0.5}
  \Simley{-1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great! `\usepackage{tikzemoticon}` and then all eyebrows etc. is set by parameters.

Comment: @percusse: What?? There is a package for this already??? You should post an answer with an example.

Comment: No, no. I can see it coming. Sorry, hahah. I just loved the idea.

Comment: This answer is so incredibly cool. :) May I suggest lowering the mouth, as the "smiley_level" is decreasing? I tried `\draw[domain=-\eyeX:\eyeX] plot ({\x},{-0.1+#1*0.15-#1*1.75*\yScale*(sin((\x+\eyeX)/\xScale))-\eyeY});` At any rate, I favor the idea of creating a `tizemoticon` package. :)

Comment: @user1202136: Have incorporated your suggestion.

Comment: I was already searching for the tikzemoticon package before I read the third reply. :)

Answer (score 45):

Here is a rather amusing one. Please adjust further for more expressive faces.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\smiley}{\tikz[baseline=-0.75ex,black]{
    \draw circle (2mm);
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0.5pt] (left eye) at (135:0.8mm) {};
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0.5pt] (right eye) at (45:0.8mm) {};
\draw (-145:0.9mm) arc (-120:-60:1.5mm);
    }
}

\newcommand{\frownie}{\tikz[baseline=-0.75ex,black]{
    \draw circle (2mm);
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0.5pt] (left eye) at (135:0.8mm) {};
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0.5pt] (right eye) at (45:0.8mm) {};
\draw (-145:0.9mm) arc (120:60:1.5mm);
    }
}

\newcommand{\neutranie}{\tikz[baseline=-0.75ex,black]{
    \draw circle (2mm);
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0.5pt] (left eye) at (135:0.8mm) {};
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0.5pt] (right eye) at (45:0.8mm) {};
\draw (-135:0.9mm) -- (-45:0.9mm);
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Pros, Cons and others}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[\smiley] Yay!
    \item[\frownie] Bah!
    \item[\neutranie] Wadeva...
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is good, how to make it colorful?

Answer (score 39):

Here is for fun a non-Tikz solution from Knuth himself. Originally published in his paper with the
apt name *Stable Husbands*.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%% Knuths smile box from 
%\centerline{\bf Stable Husbands}
%\bigskip
%\centerline{\sl Donald E. Knuth, Rajeev Motwani, and Boris Pittel}
%\centerline{\sl  Computer Science Department, Stanford University}
\def\pfbox % new experimental version (DEK, November 88)
{{\ooalign{\hfil\lower.06ex % a smiley face
 \hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\frown$}\hfil\crcr
 \hfil\lower.7ex\hbox{\"{}}\hfil\crcr
 \mathhexbox20D}}}
\begin{document}
\Huge \pfbox
\end{document}
```

And of course this is a mathematician's frown `\texttt{\meaning\frown}.` Change the `\frown` to a minus sign to get a very neutral one:

[image]

Answer (score 32):

Unicode defines lots of emoticons: There is ☺ and ☹ at `U+263A` and `U+2639`, and there are many more from `U+1F601` onward. The neutral one is  `U+1F610 NEUTRAL FACE`. So, all you need is a font that includes these characters (like DejaVu Sans) and use it with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. E.g.,

```
% Compile with xelatex or lualatex and DejaVu Sans installed on your system.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\DejaSans{DejaVu Sans}
\newcommand\good{{\color{green}\DejaSans ☺}}
\newcommand\neutral{{\color{blue}\DejaSans }}
\newcommand\bad{{\color{red}\DejaSans ☹}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item[\good] Unicode provides a lot of emoticons
    \item[\neutral] They even have cat faces: {\DejaSans }
    \item[\bad] Few fonts actually include these characters.
  \end{itemize}
  More samples: {\DejaSans }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: How can you be neutral about having cat-faced emoticons??

Comment: Using this with `pdflatex` seems to be non-trivial, so I posted [a dedicated question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82756/unicode-emoticons-with-pdflatex).

Comment: @Raphael: Just run `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex`. It doesn't hurt...

Comment: I'm sure it doesn't (`xelatex` works as well), but this particular document is supposed to work on machines/installations I don't know. :/

Comment: With `\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}` you can directly use Unicode smileys without `\DejaSans`

Answer (score 27):

**Update 4**

I'm not an emoticon expert, so I draw some basic emoticons. Finally I changed the names now I define `emoticon happy`, `emoticon sad` , `emoticon straight face` and `emoticon wink`. I would put the final library on my site now. The shapes are not perfect because, there is a problem when I add some text inside.

First I created the file: `tikzlibraryshapes.emoticon.code.tex`

```
% tikzlibraryshapes.emoticon.code.tex
% Basic emoticons
%
\pgfdeclareshape{emoticon happy}
{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=circle] 
  \inheritanchorborder[from=circle]
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south east}
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from=circle]
  %
  % Background path
  %
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from=circle]
  \beforebackgroundpath{
    \pgfutil@tempdima=\radius%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}%  
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@yb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}%
    \color{black}
    \pgfpathellipse{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfutil@tempdima}{.25\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
                   {\pgfqpoint{.1\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}%
                   {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{.15\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
                    \pgfusepath{fill}% 
    \pgfpathellipse{\pgfqpoint{-.25\pgfutil@tempdima}{.25\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
                   {\pgfqpoint{.1\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}%
                   {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{.15\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
                    \pgfusepath{fill}% 
                          \pgfusepath{stroke}%  
\begingroup
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}%
\pgflowlevelsynccm    
       \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-.353\pgfutil@tempdima}{-.353\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
      \pgfpatharc{-135}{-45}{.5\pgfutil@tempdima and .5\pgfutil@tempdima}%
      \pgfusepath{stroke}%
\endgroup    
  }} 

  \pgfdeclareshape{emoticon sad}
{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=circle] 
  \inheritanchorborder[from=circle]
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south east}
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from=circle]
  %
  % Background path
  %
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from=circle]
  \beforebackgroundpath{
    \pgfutil@tempdima=\radius%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}%  
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@yb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}%
    \color{black}
    \pgfpathellipse{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfutil@tempdima}{.25\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
                   {\pgfqpoint{.1\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}%
                   {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{.15\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
                    \pgfusepath{fill}% 
    \pgfpathellipse{\pgfqpoint{-.25\pgfutil@tempdima}{.25\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
                   {\pgfqpoint{.1\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}%
                   {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{.15\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
                    \pgfusepath{fill}% 
                          \pgfusepath{stroke}%  
\begingroup
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}%
\pgflowlevelsynccm    
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-.353\pgfutil@tempdima}{-.353\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
 \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfqpoint{-.353\pgfutil@tempdima}{-.353\pgfutil@tempdima}}
                {\pgfpoint{0pt}{-.153\pgfutil@tempdima}}
                {\pgfqpoint{.353\pgfutil@tempdima}{-.353\pgfutil@tempdima}}
      \pgfusepath{stroke}%
\endgroup    
  }}  

    \pgfdeclareshape{emoticon straight face}
{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=circle] 
  \inheritanchorborder[from=circle]
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south east}
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from=circle]
  %
  % Background path
  %
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from=circle]
  \beforebackgroundpath{
    \pgfutil@tempdima=\radius%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}%  
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@yb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}%
    \color{black}
    \pgfpathellipse{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfutil@tempdima}{.25\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
                   {\pgfqpoint{.1\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}%
                   {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{.15\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
                    \pgfusepath{fill}% 
    \pgfpathellipse{\pgfqpoint{-.25\pgfutil@tempdima}{.25\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
                   {\pgfqpoint{.1\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}%
                   {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{.15\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
                    \pgfusepath{fill}% 
                          \pgfusepath{stroke}%  
\begingroup
  \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}%
  \pgflowlevelsynccm    
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-.353\pgfutil@tempdima}{-.353\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{.353\pgfutil@tempdima}{-.353\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}%
\endgroup    
  }}  
      \pgfdeclareshape{emoticon wink}
{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=circle] 
  \inheritanchorborder[from=circle]
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base east}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south east}
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from=circle]
  %
  % Background path
  %
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from=circle]
  \beforebackgroundpath{
    \pgfutil@tempdima=\radius%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}%  
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@yb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}%
    \color{black}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-.40\pgfutil@tempdima}{.25\pgfutil@tempdima}}% 
    \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfqpoint{-.40\pgfutil@tempdima}{.25\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
                {\pgfqpoint{-.25\pgfutil@tempdima}{.10\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
                {\pgfqpoint{-.10\pgfutil@tempdima}{.25\pgfutil@tempdima}}%        
    \pgfpathellipse{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfutil@tempdima}{.25\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
                   {\pgfqpoint{.1\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}%
                   {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{.15\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
    \pgfusepath{fill}%     
    \pgfusepath{stroke}%  
\begingroup
   \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}%
   \pgflowlevelsynccm    
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-.353\pgfutil@tempdima}{-.353\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
   \pgfpatharc{-135}{-45}{.5\pgfutil@tempdima and .5\pgfutil@tempdima}%
   \pgfusepath{stroke}%
\endgroup      
  }}%        
\endinput
```

The name of the first emoticon is `emoticon :-)`. The second is `emoticon :-(`.
Here an example how to use these new shapes:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.emoticon}
\begin{document}

\vspace{1cm}
\tikz \node [shape=emoticon happy,draw,fill=yellow]  {};    
\tikz \node [shape=emoticon sad,draw,fill=yellow]  {};

\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
  \node [shape=emoticon happy,draw,scale=8,fill=orange]  {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
  \node [shape=emoticon sad,draw,scale=8,fill=orange]  {};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
  \node [shape=emoticon straight face,draw,scale=8,fill=orange]  {};
\end{tikzpicture}    
 \begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
  \node [shape=emoticon wink,draw,scale=8,fill=orange]  {};
\end{tikzpicture}     
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

The [`fontawesome` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) provides this possibility:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{description}
  \item[\faSmileO] good
  \item[\faMehO] indifferent
  \item[\faFrownO] bad
\end{description}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it's nice, what about it in LaTex?

Comment: @WangyanLi try it and you'll see: `\faFrown` (`fontawesome` is only supported in Xe/LuaLaTeX.)

Comment: With the latest version of `fontawesome`, you must use `\faSmileO`, `\faMehO` and `\faFrownO`...

Comment: @PaulGessler The `fontawesome` package works very well with `pdflatex`.

Comment: @PaulGaborit it didn't at the time this answer was written... :-) Thanks, updated for the latest version.

Answer (score 8):

I use a stack to make the `\SmileBarometer[<level>]`.  EDITED to make mood scale from -100 to 100.

EDITED to change eye color with mood.  RE-EDITED to make eyes `\Large`.

As Andrew notes in a comment, one could set up macros like `\def\SoSo{\SmileBarometer[0]}` to lock in particular moods.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx,stackengine}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\SmileBarometer[1][100]{%
  \savestack\Mouth{\if0#1\color{red}\rule{1.5ex}{.45pt}\else
    \color{red}\scalebox{.8}[#1]{\rotatebox{90}{\scalebox{.013}[1]{(}}}\fi}%
    \ifnum#1<0\relax\def\eyecolor{cyan!\the\numexpr100#1!red}\else
      \def\eyecolor{brown!\the\numexpr100-#1!cyan}\fi
  \stackinset{c}{}{c}{-2.5pt}{\Mouth}{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{c}{2pt}{\color{\eyecolor}\Large.\kern.7pt.}{\scalebox{1.5}{$\bigcirc$}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\SmileBarometer{}
\SmileBarometer[80]
\SmileBarometer[60]
\SmileBarometer[0]
\SmileBarometer[-60]
\SmileBarometer[-80]
\SmileBarometer[-100]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I might suggest setting up macros for these percentages instead, e.g. `\superDuper`, `\meh`, `\dontAsk` ...

Answer (score 2):

There is the [`tikzsymbols`](http://ctan.mirror.norbert-ruehl.de/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzsymbols/tikzsymbols.pdf) package which has some small variety of 2D and 3D smileys.
My MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikzsymbols}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Everything between \textbackslash frowney and \textbackslash smiley}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item[\cChangey{2}] There is even Schrödingers Cat \SchrodingersCat{0}
            \item[\cChangey{0}] Some commands are also available in German 
            \item[\cChangey{-2}] None \dTongey
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

And here is a nice Story showing some of the smileys https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/227226/217553

Answer (score 2):

## With Unicode and `lualatex`

You can use Unicode emojis to insert [all kinds of faces](https://emojipedia.org/people/):

[image: different emojis, mostly faces]

Here's the complete source file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newcommand{\emoji}[1]{%
  {\fontspec{Noto Color Emoji}[RawFeature={mode=harf}]{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Happy: \emoji{}
    \item Neutral: \emoji{}
    \item Not amused: \emoji{}
    \item More: \emoji{‍️❤️‍️‍‍}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Compile the file with `lualatex`.

This uses [Noto Color Emoji](https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/emoji/) as the font that renders the emojis. I installed the font on Arch Linux using

```
pacman -Sy noto-fonts-emoji
```

which put `NotoColorEmoji.ttf` in `/usr/share/fonts/noto/`.

The `\emoji` command is used to limit where text is rendered with the Noto Color Emoji font. Otherwise the non-emoji text such as "Happy: " wouldn't appear in the resulting PDF.

---

`lualatex --version` gives

> This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020/Arch Linux)