# Unicode emoticons with pdflatex

Tags: fonts, pdftex, unicode

Following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59125/3213), I tried to use Unicode emoticons with `pdflatex` like so:

```
{\fontfamily{DejaVuSans-TLF}\selectfont }
```

The font is selected but the emoticon does not show.

There are some [TTF fonts](http://shapecatcher.com/unicodefonts.html) which support the characters, such as Symbola, but apparently getting TTF fonts to work with `pdflatex` is [a pain in the butt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1472/3213).

Is there a way out?

Comment: Fonts in `pdflatex` have only up to 256 characters.

Comment: @egreg Is that a "no way, you have to use (XeLa|Lua)Tex"? I guess using actual images or drawing them with TikZ (access via `newunicodechar`) would be a way out, if a tedious one.

Comment: You could use `otftotfm` to create a font with the desired glyphs from DejaVu, but it would be very time consuming. Probably getting them as pictures (maybe PDF files built with `standalone` via XeLaTeX) and then using `\newunicodechar` to access them.

Comment: You can use the `coloremoji` package, which will insert the images from Apple’s fonts.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Prepare the following file

```
% smilie.tex
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

and compile it with XeLaTeX. Then you can use the glyph via the so built PDF file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newunicodechar{}{\includegraphics{smilie}}

\begin{document}
Here is a .
\end{document}
```

[image]

Probably some tweaking with the borders in the `standalone` file is necessary.

You can get the height of an uppercase letter in the current font by saying

```
\includegraphics[height=\fontcharht\font`A]{smilie}
```

Comment: Sweet. Feels like playing Jenga with a sledgehammer, though. ;)

Comment: On second thought, this approach is mechanical enough to make a script of it. Take list of symbols, create a pdf for each of them and then create an `sty` defining all the `newunicodechar` mappings. One minor problem remains: included PDFs don't scale with the font size. Can this be added?

Comment: @Raphael I've added a way to scale the symbol

Comment: Can you have `\includegraphics` adjust color and background-color of the symbol?

Comment: @UlrichDiez I don't think so.

Comment: In my case the PDF generated from the `smilie.tex` file was too wide. I was able to solve this by using `\documentclass[crop]{standalone}`

Answer (score 14):

Here is my solution which is partially based on another post from tex.sx I am afraid I cannot find again:

**In a nutshell:** Download SVG from a database like twemoji (used by Twitter), convert it and scale it appropriately. Pros: Looks exactly like on Twitter or any other platform you desire. Does not require XeLaTeX. Con: Does not work completely automated.

We make an example of the proposed process by inserting the  emoji into a TeX document.

1. **Find the unicode of your emoji**

   Using [Google Fu](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=%F0%9F%A6%84%20unicode), we find out that the code point for our emoji is `U+1F984`.
2. **Download an SVG file of the emoji**

   Be sure to use one consistent data source for all of your tweets.
   We are referring to [twemoji](https://twemoji.twitter.com/) for doing this.

   Download the SVG file from twemoji by adjusting this link:
   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twitter/twemoji/master/assets/svg/1f984.svg
3. **Convert the SVG file into an EPS file**

   There are certain packages for doing so such as `includesvg`, but I don't want to install `inkscape` on my machine, so I use an online converter:

   Go to https://convertio.co/de/svg-eps/ and insert the URL from step 2. Download the converted file into your LaTeX figures folder.
4. **Typeset the emoji in LaTeX**

   This is how I could typeset emojis the best way in LaTeX:

   ```tex
   \usepackage{textcomp}  % Required for encoding \textbigcircle
   \usepackage{scalerel}  % Required for emoji \scalerel

   \def\{\scalerel*{\includegraphics{figures/1f984.eps}}{\textrm{\textbigcircle}}}
   ```

   To use it, just write something like:

   ```tex
   I like \s, and what's about you?
   ```

And here is MWE for it: https://overleaf.com/read/tjngsyvrfcmy

**PS:** I always like to hear your simpler ideas!

Comment: Using eps files causes trouble for me, but this also works with converting the svg to a pdf, e.g. with `inkscape 1f680.svg --export-pdf=1f680.pdf`.

Answer (score 2):

I use a setup with 3 files: the list of macros/symbols in UTF8 `do-emoji.tex`:

```
% Names below are arbitrary; a macro with this name will be defined.
% After editing the list in the next row, (re)run:    xelatex emoji-from-list
\foreach [count=\P] \M/\C in {smilie/,ghost/,pumpkin/}
   {\doEmoji{\C}{\M}{\P}}
```

(I think one should avoid whitespace in the list in the first row.)  Then the rendering file `emoji-from-list.tex`:

```
\documentclass[multi=my,crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Symbola}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\doEmoji[3]{%    character, macroname, page
  \begin{my}#1\end{my}}
\include{do-emoji}
\end{document}
```

(process with `xelatex emoji-from-list`).  Finally, the actual LaTeX file includes:

```
\newcommand\includeEmoji[1]{%   With CM fonts and 1.28, it ascends to the top of the capitals, and descends to the bottom of comma.
  \ensuremath{\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[page=#1,height=1.28\fontcharht\font`A]{emoji-from-list}}}}}

{\newcommand\doEmoji[3]{%   character, macroname, page
    \expandafter\xdef\csname #2\endcsname{\noexpand\includeEmoji{#3}}%
    \edef\next{\noexpand\includeEmoji{#3}}%         % would need more expansion in the next row otherwise
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\Gnewunicodechar\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter#1\expandafter}%
       \expandafter{\next}% % (#1=\C)
 }%  For a preamble common for several docs: do nothing if file is not present:
 \IfFileExists{do-emoji.tex}{\input{do-emoji}}{}}
```

After this, either use a macro (named in `do-emoji.tex`), or just use the UTF-8 character.  (If you do not need macro names, give the same fake name to all of the characters in the list.)  It is easy to auto-generate the file `do-emoji.tex`.

**NOTES:**

1. I optimize for usage in math; so I use larger emoji than in other
   answers, and they are `\vcenter`⸣ed.
2. Above, a macro `\Gnewunicodechar` is used.  If you do not plan to
   use these Unicode chars in your document, just remove the last two
   lines inside the definition of `\doEmoji` above.
3. I do not know about `utf8`, but for `utf8x`, `\Gnewunicodechar`
   may be defined as this:

   ```
   \def\UNItoNUMz{%        Actually, do not need hex in what follows!
     \edef\OUT{\the\count0}%
   }
   \def\UNItoNUMcont#1#2{%
     \multiply\count0 64\relax
     \advance\count0 -"80\relax
     \advance\count0 `#2\relax
     #1}

   \def\UNItoNUM#1{%       No attempt is made to detect out-of-range bytes
     \count0=`#1%
     \ifnum`#1<"C0\relax   % In the range a0..bf would give false positives
       \let\next=\UNItoNUMz
     \else
       \ifnum`#1<"E0\relax
         \advance\count0 -"C0\relax
         \def\next{\UNItoNUMcont\UNItoNUMz}
       \else
         \ifnum`#1<"F0\relax
           \advance\count0 -"E0\relax
           \def\next{\UNItoNUMcont{\UNItoNUMcont\UNItoNUMz}}
         \else
           \ifnum`#1<"F8\relax
             \advance\count0 -"F0\relax
             \def\next{\UNItoNUMcont{\UNItoNUMcont{\UNItoNUMcont\UNItoNUMz}}}
           \fi
         \fi
       \fi
     \fi
     \next}

   \newcommand\Gnewunicodechar[2]{{%   (Since we need global for \foreach, localize changes anyway.)  Specific for utf8x
     \def\gdefUNI##1##2{%
       \expandafter\let\csname uc@temp@a\endcsname\global\csname uni@declcharopt\endcsname{##1}{document}{##2}}%
     \UNItoNUM#1%                  % (#1=\C; sets \OUT); This is for utf8x; in utf8, may need something else
     \gdefUNI{\OUT}{#2}%       % finish definition
   }}
   ```
4. **Update**: I changed `\include` to (the most robust combination of) `\input` and `\IfFileExists`.  The reason: `\include` may create a spurious pagebreak.  One should also consider the variant in the first comment below.

Comment: With `amsmath`, one can change the last line of definition of `\includeEmoji` to `\text{$\mathsurround0pt\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[page=#1,height=1.28\fontcharht\font``A]{emoji-from-list}}}$}}` (replace double-backtick to single one).  Then Unicode chars work fine in sub/superscripts too.