# Find which font is used by xelatex

Tags: fonts, xetex, windows

I posted an answer about including Unicode into `pdflatex` documents (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/399571/81006), but in fact this answer (while working) demonstrates problems with `xelatex` (on Windows 7).

**Summary:** `xelatex` chooses a different font than the installed on Windows font.

Running this example through `xelatex`

```
\documentclass[multi=my,crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmainfont{Symbola}
\begin{document}

smilie/,ghost/,pumpkin/.

\end{document}
```

produces [image: xelatex output with Symbola]

On the other hand, in `Symbola` the same string in Character Map (and any other Windows application I checked) produces: [image: rendered with Character Map]; note that a different rendition of GHOST is chosen.  Inspecting the installed TTF file of `Symbola` with a font editor shows the latter glyph for HOST, and no variation selectors.

Moreover, if I change commenting in LaTeX file to choose `DejaVu Sans` instead of `Symbola`, then only rectangles are shown instead of characters.  (While `DejaVu Sans` does not have `GHOST` and `JACK-O-LANTERN`, it does have `SMILIE`.)

**Question:**  how to find which *exactly* font (file?) was used by `xelatex`?  (I suspect that it picks up one of the older version of `DejaVu/Symbola` which are left in `%SYSTEMROOT%/Fonts` by the Windows’ font installation subsystem when newer versions of a font are installed.)

Comment: Not an answer, but you can specify a font by filename with `fontspec`: `\setmainfont{Symbola_hint.ttf}[Path = /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ancient-scripts/]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XeLaTeX compiles your document to an intermediate format called Extended DVI before outputting it to PDF.  Unfortunately, the XDV driver is not really verbose by default.  Therefore, we first compile the document to the XDV format using

```
xelatex -no-pdf test.tex
```

and from there we call the driver with the `-v` option

```
xdvipdfmx -v test.xdv
```

On my machine, this outputs to the console

```
<FONTMAP:/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map><FONTMAP:/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap/kanjix.map><FONTMAP:/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/ckx.map>test.xdv -> test.pdf
DVI Comment:  XeTeX output 2017.11.04:1642
<AGL:texglyphlist.txt><AGL:pdfglyphlist.txt><AGL:glyphlist.txt>[1</usr/share/fonts/truetype/ancient-scripts/Symbola_hint.ttf@9.96pt<NATIVE-FONTMAP:/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ancient-scripts/Symbola_hint.ttf/0/H/65536/0/0>
pdf_font>> Input encoding "Identity-H" requires at least 2 bytes.
pdf_font>> The -m <00> option will be assumed for "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ancient-scripts/Symbola_hint.ttf".
(CID:Symbola)
pdf_font>> Type0 font "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ancient-scripts/Symbola_hint.ttf" cmap_id=<Identity-H,0> opened at font_id=</usr/share/fonts/truetype/ancient-scripts/Symbola_hint.ttf/0/H/65536/0/0,0>.
>]
otf_cmap>> Creating ToUnicode CMap for "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ancient-scripts/Symbola_hint.ttf"...
(CID:/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ancient-scripts/Symbola_hint.ttf[CIDFontType2])
Compression saved 52936 bytes
7360 bytes written
```

Comment: I presume you mean “outputs to ‘console’” instead of “to command line”…  In fact, one does not need a driver: the `.xdv` file already contains the full path — and it is wrong indeed: `C:/windows/fonts/Symbola.ttf` — while the latest, currently active, version is in `Symbola-hints.ttf`.  So it is a bug in `xelatex` (of TeXLive-2016, BTW).  Thanks!

Comment: Investigating the registry, I see that `xetex` should have used a moral analogue of `reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts" -f Symbola` — which emits `Symbola (TrueType)    REG_SZ    Symbola_hint.ttf`.

Answer (score 3):

Following [XeTeX documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/xetex/xetexref/xetex-reference.pdf), I inserted

```
\XeTeXtracingfonts=1\relax
```

near beginning of document.  It it very buggy, but still `.log` file contains guessable info (interlaced with overwritten memory :-[):

```
Requested font "DejaVu Sans" at 10.0pt
 -> 5^^I/windows/fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf
```

(the correct file name on my system is `DejaVuSans_2.ttf` — since it is the 3rd version installed).