# Fontspec: Misplaced hacek above i when loading TeX Gyre Pagella with fontspec

Tags: fontspec, accents

When I load TeX Gyre Pagella using `fontspec`'s `setmainfont` command and try to use a hacek above an `i`, it is misplaced.

[image: bad hacek i]

The reason I am using `fontspec` is because I want old style numbers to be the default, and I can set that with `fontspec`'s `setmainfont`.

If I instead load TeX Gyre Pagella using `fontenc` and `tgpagella`, the hacek is aligned properly.

[image: good hacek i]

However, if I do this, I have to manually specify that I want to use old style numbers using `\oldstylenums{}`, which is a real pain (including specifying them in things like enumerated lists, page numbers, etc., which requires manually tweaking a bunch of things I'd rather not have to mess with).

Is there a way to load the correct glyph while still using `fontspec`? Or else some way to manually adjust it to look right?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{tgpagella} % These work for \v{\i}, but no default old style numbers

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{TeX Gyre Pagella} % Default old style numbers, but bad \v{\i}

\begin{document}
    \v{\i}
\end{document}
```

Edit: As Thérèse's comment makes apparent, it might be relevant that I'm using XeLaTeX.

Comment: I can’t reproduce the problem with either luatex or xetex in an up-to-date TeX Live.

Comment: Hmmm... Just updated and it is working in LuaLaTeX, but still not in XeLaTeX for me. Since I'm using XeLaTeX, I'll leave this open.

Comment: I also can't reproduce. Do you have more than one version of the font installed? (i.e., in TeX tree and system font.)

Comment: Not sure—how could I tell?

Comment: I guess that depends on your OS. But assuming file names are the same (not necessarily true) do a search for `texgyrepagella-regular.otf`

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/399585/87678 for how to find what font xelatex is using

Comment: Okay, when I do this I see that the working one (fontenc + tgpagella packages) seems to load Simple Font "qplr," while the incorrect one loads texgyrepagella-regular.otf. I'm guessing this means it is installed twice and I should get rid of the system font?

Edit: Yup, that fixed it. This could be closed or deleted now; not sure which would be best.

Comment: I don't think the `tgpagella` package is using `fontspec` at all. `qplr` is an 8bit font. If `lualatex` is working, you want to compare which font that is using with what `xelatex` is picking up.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue on my system. TeX Gyre Pagella Version 2.501;PS 2.501;ffdkm 0.1

Comment: @Jigsaw you certainly to not want to use `[T1]{fontenc}` with xelatex (all hyphenation will be wrong for any words with non ascii letters) if using xelatex you need to use teh opentype version of the font. `texgyrepagella-regular.otf` (but check you don't have an old copy installed sonewhere masking the version that comes with texlive)

Comment: add also `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1` to your document and check what the log says about the actual font uses