# Generating color-neutral PDF with `xelatex`

Tags: xetex, color, pdf, includegraphics

(This is based on my workaround related to my answer to [using emoticons with `pdflatex`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82756/unicode-emoticons-with-pdflatex/399571#399571) — this workaround is discussed in [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65071/change-color-in-finished-pdf-file/675859#675859)).  The gist is: it turns out that in the years after I posted the answer, *the behavior of `xelatex` changed*!

Up to `TeXLive2018`, the PDF files produced by `xelatex` were “color-neutral”: when `\includegraphics`ed, they would inherit the current foreground color from the parent document.  However, with `TeXLive2021` the generated PDF file has color-setting commands.  **The result:** one must binary-edit (***unreliable*** and inconvenient) this PDF file before it may be fully used in other documents.  (The details of the change and which postprocessing is needed is discussed in  [the link above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65071/change-color-in-finished-pdf-file/675859#675859).  The core is the following change:)

```
- q 1 0 0 1 72 -62.967 cm                 BT /F1 9.9626 Tf -72 64.65 Td[<1841>]TJ ET Q
+ q 1 0 0 1 72 -62.967 cm 0 G 0 g 0 g 0 G BT /F1 9.9626 Tf -72 64.65 Td[<1841>]TJ ET Q
```

**Question:** is there a way to advice `xelatex` to not use color-setting commands?

---

In more detail: with the input file like

```latex
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}  % https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/
\begin{document}
⇢
\end{document}
```

then uncompressing with `pdftk file.pdf output uncompress-file.pdf uncompress` (every) page’s content looks like what is shown above.

---

To test color-neutrality, one can include the generated `PDF` file as in:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\color{red}\includegraphics[height=1in]{emoji-from-list.pdf}
\end{document}
```

(with color-neutral included `PDF` file the content should be red).

Comment: I really don't like it if I have to follow up three links only to understand what a question is about. Please make your question self contained, links should only be references.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I wrote it this way *because I thought* it is self-contained.  I thought that the links are needed only to explain the motivations!  I still do not understand which parts of the linked questions would help you understand what *the question is about*.  Hints?

Comment: Your question is missing an example that can be used for a test.

Comment: Yes, thanks!  Testing your examples, this became clear — so now I think it is better.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to compile with

```
xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -c" file
```

For

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\sys_ensure_backend:
\pdf_uncompress:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

it changes the stream from

```
stream
 q 1 0 0 1 72 769.89 cm 0 G 0 g BT /F1 9.9626 Tf 76.712 -62.765 Td[<001c0023>-28<002b>]TJ 154.421 -567.87 Td[<0052>]TJ ET Q

endstream
```

to

```
stream
 q 1 0 0 1 72 769.89 cm BT /F1 9.9626 Tf 76.712 -62.765 Td[<001c0023>-28<002b>]TJ 154.421 -567.87 Td[<0052>]TJ ET Q

endstream
```

As an alternative use lualatex.

Comment: `lualatex` **works indeed**, thanks (with `TeXLive2021`)!  Unfortunately, with `xelatex` and the driver `xdvipdfmx` the output (with `TeXLive2021`) still contains `0 G 0 g`.  In more detail: the code you gave does not compile; removing the preamble (and uncompressing with `pdftk`) shows color-setting commands.

Comment: works fine for me in texlive 2021 (it fails in 2020), are you sure that you used the `-c` option?  And there is no need to use pdftk, you can set the compresslevel with the `-z` option (that is what `\pdf_uncompress:` is doing).

Comment: Thanks for `-z`.  (Since `xelatex` and `lualatex` are useless on my system, I do not know anything about their command-line syntax.)  Yes, I’m sure about `-c` option!  Anything else I can do for debugging?

Comment: BTW, while `lualatex` works (and does not take minute[s] to finish!), it produces wrong PDF.  An obsolete version of the requested font is used.  Is it a bug, or an expected behavior?

Comment: Same results with `-no-pdf` and then running `xdvipdfmx -c -z 0 emoji-from-list.xdv `.  The producer is `xdvipdfmx (20210318)`.  (Already the first generated object — №6 — contains `0 g 0 G`.)

Comment: my xdvipdfmx on texlive 2021 is a bit newer (xdvipdfmx Version 20211117), it is quite possible that windows got an update that other systems got only with tl2022. Regarding fonts with lualatex: the log-file shows which fonts lualatex uses, and with the fontspec options (e.g. Path) it is possible to configure that.

Comment: `TeXLive2021` was released 2021-03-25.  It cannot contain anything that new.  See [https://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/texlive/2021/](https://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/texlive/2021/).  You must have updated after this release…

Comment: On windows it can. We get updates of some binaries during the year. I remember that I could test some new features earlier.

Comment: I’m on windows.  No updates. (Without my — manual — actions.)  [I do not update manually — for me a reproducible state is much more important than getting new exciting bugs in unpredictable moments.]