# Removing part of a symbol or image

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

Tidying up and posing a secondary question which was answered

I'm trying to put together a visual aid of people numbers in a particular area, so I imagine using something like. Answered elsewhere using the `marvosym` package with `\Gentsroom` as the symbol.

[image: Man image]

Is there an easy way to shade out half the image e.g. If I'm using each figure to represent four people and I want to indicate 2 by using half a figure?

Link to earlier question below
[Question on human shape in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84275/custom-human-shape-for-tikz/84283#comment181386_84283)

Note: The title is terrible but all I can think of. Please feel free to edit it.

Comment: “Shade” reads like you want to shade it, i.e making it gray-ish. “Using half a figure” reads like the title should be “Removing part of a symbol or image”.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

(This answer was migrated from the [original question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84275/custom-human-shape-for-tikz/84283#comment181386_84283))

If I understood correctly the question, the following code may help to devise an appropiate solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=2mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\rowofmen#1{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2mm,y=3mm]
\path[clip] (0,0) rectangle (#1,1.1);
\pgfmathparse{ceil(#1)}
\foreach \i in {0,...,\pgfmathresult} {
\node[inner sep=0pt, above right] at (\i, 0) 
   {\resizebox{2mm}{3mm}{\Gentsroom}};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
\textcolor{gray}{\rowofmen{5}}\\
\textcolor{black!.3!blue}{\rowofmen{3.5}}\\
\rlap{\textcolor{red}{\rowofmen{5}}}%
\rlap{\textcolor{blue}{\rowofmen{3.7}}}%
\rlap{\textcolor{green}{\rowofmen{2.5}}}%
\\    
\end{document}
```

Macro `\rowofmen{x}` produces a row of *x* men, allowing for fractional values of *x* (the trick is to draw one more man and clipping the resulting figure). Superimposing several of these rows with different colors and lenghts (as in the `\rlap` example), you can simulate half-shaded men. This is the output:

[image: Output]

Note that each man was resized to 2mm x 3mm. You can alter this by changing the parameters `x=2mm,y=3mm` of the `tikzpicture` and those of `\resizebox`. The remaining can be left unchanged.

Answer (score 13):

I'd clip the symbol with Ti*k* Z instead of drawing a white rectangle over a part of it. That way this also works in front of colored things without having an white box appearing.

I also used the `pgfinterruptboundingbox` environment so that the dimensions of `\Gentsroom` are known before I can `\clip` parts of it (this works similar to `\?lap`).
Because the `\Gentsroom` is measured this works in lieu with `\Large` and similar font-size macros.

### Macros

#### `\LeftGent[<>]{<opt>}` and `\RightGent[<>]{<opt>}`

Is an (empty) optional argument `<>` given, then the partly symbol will take the full width of the original symbol.

```
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\setlength{\fboxrule}{.2pt}
\fbox{\LeftGent{}\Gentsroom\RightGent{}} \fbox{\LeftGent[]{}\Gentsroom\RightGent[]{}}
```

[image]

The mandatory argument `<opt>` (which can be empty, but has to be given) is given to the `\node`s:

```
\RightGent{opacity=.2}\LeftGent{}\RightGent{}\LeftGent{yshift=-.5ex,red}
```

[image]

#### `\partGent[<>]{<opt>}{<perc>}` and `\trapGent[<>]{<opt>}{<perc>}`

Additional to `<>` and `<opt>` these macros take an addition argument `<perc>` so it is possible to use any arbitrary part of the symbol. Only values between `0.0` and `1.0` make sense, of course.

#### `\rowOfGents[<>]{<opt>}{<count>}` and `worOfGents[<>]{<opt>}{<count>}`

These macros build an entire row of men. `<>` and `<opt>` act as usual. `<count>` gives the (floating) number of symbols that should be typeset.

```
\rowOfGents{green}{2.5}\worOfGents{blue}{0.5}\rowOfGents{blue}{0.7}\worOfGents{red}{1.3}\par
\Large\rowOfGents{green}{2.5}\worOfGents{blue}{.5}\rowOfGents{blue}{.7}\worOfGents{red}{1.3}
```

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newif\ifclipme
\newcommand*{\LeftGent}[2][\clipmetrue]{\reflectbox{\RightGent[#1]{#2}}}
\newcommand*{\RightGent}[2][\clipmetrue]{\partGent[#1]{#2}{.5}}
\newcommand*{\trapGent}[3][\clipmetrue]{\reflectbox{\partGent[#1]{#2}{#3}}}
\newcommand*{\partGent}[3][\clipmetrue]{%
  \sbox0{\Gentsroom}%
  \tikz[baseline]
  { #1
    \ifclipme\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}\fi
    \node [anchor=south, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, text width=\wd0, text height=\ht0, text depth=\dp0, #2] (A) {}; %
    \ifclipme\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}\fi
    \clip (A.south west) rectangle ($(A.north west)!#3!(A.north east)$);
    \node [anchor=base, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, #2] {\Gentsroom};
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\rowOfGents}[3][\clipmetrue]{%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\fullGents{int(#3)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\partGents{mod(#3,1)}%
  \ifnum\fullGents>0\relax\foreach \i in {1,...,\fullGents}{\partGent[#1]{#2}{1}}\fi%
  \ifdim\partGents pt>0.0pt\relax\partGent[#1]{#2}{\partGents}\fi%
}
\newcommand*{\worOfGents}[3][\clipmetrue]{\reflectbox{\rowOfGents[#1]{#2}{#3}}}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\setlength{\fboxrule}{.2pt}
\fbox{\LeftGent{}\Gentsroom\RightGent{}} \fbox{\LeftGent[]{}\Gentsroom\RightGent[]{}}
\RightGent{opacity=.2}\LeftGent{}\RightGent{}\LeftGent{yshift=-.5ex,red}% That's gonna hurt!

\rowOfGents{green}{2.5}\worOfGents{blue}{0.5}\rowOfGents{blue}{0.7}\worOfGents{red}{1.3}\par
\Large\rowOfGents{green}{2.5}\worOfGents{blue}{0.5}\rowOfGents{blue}{0.7}\worOfGents{red}{1.3}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `tikz` to draw a white rectangle over the area you want to clip.  Below are two macros `\RightHalf` and `\LeftHalf` depending on which side you want to clip:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\RightHalf}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \node [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (A) {\Gentsroom};
  \draw [draw=none,fill=white] (A.south west) rectangle (A.north);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\LeftHalf}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \node [inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (A) {\Gentsroom};
  \draw [draw=none,fill=white] (A.south east) rectangle (A.north);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document} 

\RightHalf \Gentsroom \Gentsroom \LeftHalf 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also a solution without TikZ:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\newcommand{\RightHalf}{\clipbox{2.195pt 0 0 0}{\Gentsroom}}
\newcommand{\LeftHalf}{\clipbox{0 0 2.195pt 0}{\Gentsroom}}
\usepackage{trimclip}
\begin{document}

% ======== to compute the magic constant 2.195pt above: ========
\setbox0=\hbox{\Gentsroom}
\the\wd0  % 4.39pt, divide it by 2 to get 2.195pt

\RightHalf \Gentsroom \Gentsroom \LeftHalf 
\end{document}
```

Alternatively you can also choose to compute the magic constants in "runtime" instead of hard coding it:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{trimclip}
\begin{document}


\begingroup
\setbox0=\hbox{\Gentsroom}
\dimen0=\wd0  % after this, dimen0 = width of a \Gentsroom symbol
\divide\dimen0 by2  % after this, dimen0 = half the width of a \Gentsroom symbol
\def\tmp #1{
    \endgroup
    \newcommand\RightHalf{\clipbox{#1 0 0 0}{\Gentsroom}}  % substitute its value into occurrences of #1 here
    \newcommand\LeftHalf{\clipbox{0 0 #1 0}{\Gentsroom}}
}
\expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\the\dimen0}


\RightHalf \Gentsroom \Gentsroom \LeftHalf 
\end{document}
```

Ref: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201623/250119

Comment: Or expl3 `box_trim:Nnnnn` see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/331788/250119