# Drawing system architecture in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm pretty new to Tikz. How can I draw the below graph in Tikz?[image: system]

I will break up my questions into small pieces.

1. How can I group a bunch of objects and form a big one?
2. How can I zoom an object and place detailed objects into the zoomed container?
3. How to draw a human figure?
4. How to scatter objects inside a container without predefined placement info?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Not sure if it applies here, but, perhaps [tikz-UML](http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/) package can be useful.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84420/removing-part-of-a-symbol-or-image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is too complicated for a comment.  It is based on Gregor Perčič's solution.

First, you can simplify drawing rectangles.  Second, using a scope you can move a group of objects around using the shift key, and create a node (more or less) using the local bounding box key.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[shift={(1,1)},local bounding box=A]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (11.3,1.5);
\draw (0.2,0.2) rectangle (3.2,1);
\draw (3.7,0.2) rectangle (6.7,1);
\draw (7.2,0.2) rectangle (10.2,1);
\node[scale=0.8] at (1.65,0.5) {$S_{x_{1}}$};
\node[scale=0.8] at (5.5,0.5) {$S_{x_{2}}$};
\node[scale=0.8] at (8.5,0.5) {$S_{x_{3}}$};
\node[scale=0.8] at (10.65,0.5) {$S_{x}$};
\end{scope}

\draw[->] (0,0) -- (A.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, this is nice. Can I add some randomization to inner rectangles placement?

Comment: I'm actually somewhat ashamed that I couldn't find a better way to construct the diagram. I've been using Tikz for a long time, but for this example, it seems to me, there isn't any witty solution. John, can you perhaps help me improve my Tikz skills? I'd be grateful.

Comment: @GregorPerčič - It is not unusual to ask questions here about better ways of doing things.  That is how I learned a lot of useful tricks.