# tikz interaction between `fit` and relative positioning of scopes

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

There seems to be a weird interaction between the `fit` package and relative positioning of scopes in `tikz`, as in, I don't understand why things happen the way they do. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\acr[1]{#1}

\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{anacat/.style={anchor=north west,minimum height=1.5em,x=.3cm,y=.25cm,every node/.style={scale=0.3}}}
\tikzset{bin/.style={draw=black,anchor=west,text width=3cm}}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1.5cm]
  \begin{scope}[shift={(0,0)},local bounding box=Hyy,anacat]
    \node[rotate=90,anchor=north,align=center] at (0,3) {$H\to\gamma\gamma$};
    \node[bin] at (1,0) {low $p_{\textrm{T}t}$};
    \node[bin] at (1,1) {high $p_{\textrm{T}t}$};
    \node[bin] at (1,2) {\acr{VBF} loose (\acr{MVA})};
    \node[bin] at (1,3) {\acr{VBF} tight (\acr{MVA})};
    \node[bin] at (1,4) {\acr{VH} leptonic};
    \node[bin] at (1,5) {$VH$ leptonic};
    \node[bin] at (1,6) {$t\bar{t}H$ leptonic};  
  \end{scope}
  \node[draw,dotted,fit=(Hyy)] (Hyybox) {};
  %      \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-1)},local bounding box=HZZ,anacat]
  \begin{scope}[shift={(Hyy.south west)},local bounding box=HZZ,anacat]
    \node[rotate=90,anchor=north,align=center] at (0,2) {$H\to ZZ$};
    \node[bin] at (1,0) {ggF $n_{j}=0$};
    \node[bin] at (1,1) {ggF $n_{j}=1$};
    \node[bin] at (1,2) {\acr{VBF} leptonic};
    \node[bin] at (1,3) {\acr{VH} leptonic};
    \node[bin] at (1,4) {\acr{VH} hadronic};
  \end{scope}
  \node[draw,dotted,fit=(HZZ)] {};
  %      \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-2.15)},local bounding box=HWW,anacat]
  \begin{scope}[shift={(HZZ.south west)},local bounding box=HWW,anacat]
    \node[rotate=90,anchor=north,align=center] at (0,2.5) {$H\to WW$};
    \node[bin] at (1,0) {ggF $n_{j}=0$};
    \node[bin] at (1,1) {ggF $n_{j}=1$};
    \node[bin] at (1,2) {ggF $n_{j}\geq 2$};
    \node[bin] at (1,3) {\acr{VBF} $n_{j}\geq 2$};
    \node[bin] at (1,4) {\acr{WH}};
    \node[bin] at (1,5) {\acr{ZH}};
  \end{scope}
  \node[draw,dotted,fit=(HWW)] {};
  %      \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-3))},local bounding box=Hbb,anacat]
  \begin{scope}[shift={(HWW.south west)},local bounding box=Hbb,anacat]
    \node[rotate=90,anchor=north,align=center] at (0,2) {$H\to b\bar{b}$};
    \node[bin] at (1,1) {\acr{MVA} low $p_{\textrm{T}^V}$};
    \node[bin] at (1,2) {\acr{MVA} low $p_{\textrm{T}^V}$};
    \node[bin] at (1,3) {$\cdots$};
  \end{scope}
  \node[draw,dotted,fit=(Hbb)] {};
  %      \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-3.45)},local bounding box=Htt,anacat]
  \begin{scope}[shift={(Hbb.south west)},local bounding box=Htt,anacat]
    \node[rotate=90,anchor=north,align=center] at (0,1) {$H\to \tau\bar{\tau}$};
    \node[bin] at (1,1) {$\cdots$};
  \end{scope}
  \node[draw,dotted,fit=(Htt)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here's how I would have expected it to look like (these are the commented-out lines):

[image: good]

Here's how it actually looks like instead:

[image: bad]

PS: This is a follow-up question for [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374560/flowcharts-within-flowcharts).

Comment: You can't use `anchor=north west` to position the scope. It is not a node. Stuff inside it gets placed wherever it would get placed without `local bounding box`. The `local bounding box=Hyy` just names whatever the result ends up being. So the style `anacat` doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: the style is mostly to propagate the `text height`, I can take out the `anchor` part. but the question how to place scopes relative to each other still remains.

Comment: But you can't place a scope the way you place a node. You have to place the nodes. You can use something like `shift` to shift everything in the scope. But you can't treat the scope as a whole.

Comment: Note that your example is very far from minimal. You only really need 2 scopes with a couple of nodes each to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit easier if you place nodes relatively. For example, here's a more minimal version of your example. The remainder of the diagram can be completed using the same pattern used for the lower scope here.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\acr[1]{#1}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
  anacat/.style={minimum height=1.5em,x=.3cm,y=.25cm,every node/.style={scale=0.3}},
  bin/.style={draw=black,anchor=west,text width=3cm},
}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1.5cm]
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=Hyy,anacat]
    \node (p-0) [bin] at (1,0) {low $p_{\textrm{T}t}$};
    \foreach \i [count=\j, remember=\j as \jlast (initially 0)] in {{high $p_{\textrm{T}t}$},{\acr{VBF} loose (\acr{MVA})},{\acr{VBF} tight (\acr{MVA})},{\acr{VH} leptonic},{$VH$ leptonic},{$t\bar{t}H$ leptonic}}
    \node (p-\j) [below=2.5mm of p-\jlast.west, bin] {\i} ;
  \end{scope}
  \node (p-l) [rotate=90,anchor=south,align=center,yshift=.5mm, scale=.3] at (Hyy.west) {$H\to\gamma\gamma$};
  \node[draw,dotted,fit=(Hyy) (p-l)] (Hyybox) {};
  \begin{scope}[shift=(Hyy.south -| p-0.west),local bounding box=HZZ,anacat]
    %     ;
    \node (q-0) [below=5mm of p-6.west, bin] {ggF $n_{j}=0$};
    \foreach \i [count=\j, remember=\j as \jlast (initially 0)] in {{ggF $n_{j}=1$},{\acr{VBF} leptonic},{\acr{VH} leptonic},{\acr{VH} hadronic}}
    \node (q-\j) [below=2.5mm of q-\jlast.west, bin] {\i} ;
    \node (q-l) [rotate=90,anchor=center,align=center] at (p-l |- HZZ.west) {$H\to ZZ$};
  \end{scope}
  \node [draw,dotted,fit=(HZZ)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: upper and lower scopes]

You could also use the `chains` library, although it is deprecated. (The equivalent involves using the graphs syntax, but it is much less straightforward to use.) However, that library has bugs which won't get fixed due to its status. Nonetheless, `chains` would simplify the code here by abstracting away from the looping.

Alternatively, you could think of the diagram as a single tree which never branches. Then the `trees` library, the builtin trees syntax or one of the more specialised packages, such as Forest or `tikz-qtree`, would be options.