# I am trying to draw this picture with latex

Tags: diagrams

I have recently presented statistics of breast cancer and made a powerpoint image:

[image]

Please notice that the icons are not exactly the same (I was lucky enough to find similar icons with different colours). I was wondering if I could draw this with latex. I am writing my M.Sc. thesis.

Comment: The only difference is with the black one which is a little bit bigger?

Comment: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/parameterised-pig/

Comment: @Johannes_B: Scary pigs ;-)

Comment: Should the pictogram of the woman been itself within LaTeX (say TikZ) or is it just the arrangement?

Comment: We can see different colors, i think they are important. What about the size? The people seem to vary in size, is this random and should be, random and should not be, or is there a system?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Perhaps: Three of thirty women will suffer from breast cancer, and one third of them will die (the black icon?)...

Comment: Please provide a code sample or specific question when asking for help on this site; otherwise the community is doing all the work for you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your figures look like the one from the symbola font:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand*{\woman}[1][gray]{{%
\fontspec{symbola} % symbola.ttf
\textcolor{#1}{%
\symbol{"1F6BA}}}}
% if you are too lazy to write many repeated commands...:
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \Repeat \prg_replicate:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document} 
\Huge
\woman\woman[magenta]\Repeat{8}{\woman}

\Repeat{3}{\woman}\woman[magenta]\Repeat{6}{\woman}

\Repeat{6}{\woman}\woman[black]\Repeat{3}{\woman}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Jonathan you are very welcome.

Answer (score 12):

With a `pic` inspired [in this one by percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84566/1952)

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    woman/.pic={    
\node[transform shape, circle,fill,minimum size=4.5mm] (head) at (0,0) {};
\node[transform shape, draw, fill, trapezium, trapezium angle=55, trapezium stretches=true, rounded corners=2pt, minimum width=0.7cm, minimum height=1cm,
,below = 1pt of head, inner sep=1pt] (body) {};
\draw[transform shape, line width=1.5mm,round cap-round cap] ([shift={(-1mm,1mm)}]body.south) --++(-90:6mm);
\draw[line width=1.5mm,round cap-round cap] ([shift={(1mm,1mm)}]body.south) --++(-90:6mm);
\draw[line width=1.25mm,round cap-round cap, rounded corners] ([yshift=-.5\pgflinewidth]body.north) --++(2.5mm,0)--++(-75:6mm);
\draw[line width=1.25mm,round cap-round cap, rounded corners] ([yshift=-.5\pgflinewidth]body.north) --++(-2.5mm,0)--++(255:6mm);
}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i [count=\ni from 0] in {1,...,10}{
\foreach \j [count=\nj from 0] in {1,...,3}{
\pic[black!30] at (\ni,-2.5*\nj) {woman};
}}

\pic[pink,scale=1.02] at (1,0) {woman};
\pic[pink,scale=1.02] at (3,-2.5) {woman};
\pic[scale=1.02] at (6,-5) {woman};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. +2 if I could.

Answer (score 10):

Not exactly the same symbol but it is a starting solution.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{standalone}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.25,yscale=.5]
\foreach \i in {1,...,10}{
\foreach \j in {1,...,3}{
\node at (\i,\j) {\textcolor{black!30}{\Ladiesroom}};
}}
\node at (2,3) {\textcolor{red}{\Ladiesroom}};
\node at (4,2) {\textcolor{red}{\Ladiesroom}};
\node at (7,1) {\textcolor{black}{\Ladiesroom}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ps:** if [this female icon](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/female/) is enough you can use the FontAwesome font.

Comment: Nice solution ;-)