# Node below icon in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have

```
\def\man#1;{%
    \begin{scope}[shift={#1}]
        \fill [rounded corners=1.5] (0,0.4) -- (0,0.8) -- (0.4,0.8) -- (0.4,0.4) --
            (0.325,0.4) -- (0.325,0.7) -- (0.3,0.7) -- (0.3,0) -- (0.225,0) --
            (0.225,0.4) -- (0.175,0.4) -- (0.175,0) -- (0.1,0) -- (0.1,0.7) --
            (0.075,0.7) -- (0.075,0.4) -- cycle;
        \fill (0.2,0.9) circle (0.1);
    \end{scope}}
\def\shadecircle(#1)(#2);{%
    \draw [thick,opacity=0.05] (#1) circle (#2);
}
```

from which I can draw a symbol of a man at (x,y)=(0,2) with

```
\man(0,2);
```

but I also want some text just below the man.

I have tried

```
\man(0,2) node [below] {my text};
```

but it doesn't produce any text.

Comment: You should take a look at `pic` in TikZ.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Manuel suggested, you can draw the `man` with a `pic` and later on place text nodes around it.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    man/.pic={%
        \fill [rounded corners=1.5] (0,0.4) -- (0,0.8) -- (0.4,0.8) -- (0.4,0.4) --
            (0.325,0.4) -- (0.325,0.7) -- (0.3,0.7) -- (0.3,0) -- (0.225,0) --
            (0.225,0.4) -- (0.175,0.4) -- (0.175,0) -- (0.1,0) -- (0.1,0.7) --
            (0.075,0.7) -- (0.075,0.4) -- cycle;
        \fill (0.2,0.9) circle (0.1);
        \coordinate (-head) at (0.2,1);
        \coordinate (-foot) at (0.2,0);
    }
%\def\shadecircle(#1)(#2);{%
%    \draw [thick,opacity=0.05] (#1) circle (#2);
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic[red] at (0,2) (myman) {man};
\node[below=1mm of myman-foot] {Some text};
\node[above=1mm of myman-head] {Some text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can find some other `men` or `women` in [I am trying to draw this picture with latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230490/1952) and [Custom "human" shape for tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84275/custom-human-shape-for-tikz/84566#84566)

*Update: Man with circle*

A circular node is drawn around the man. A `node` and not a `circle` has been used because this way all text can be placed making reference to any anchor point of this circular node.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    man/.pic={%
        \node[circle, thick, draw, fill, fill opacity=0.3, minimum size=1.3cm, outer sep=0pt] at (0.2,0.5) (-circ) {};
        \fill [rounded corners=1.5] (0,0.4) -- (0,0.8) -- (0.4,0.8) -- (0.4,0.4) --
            (0.325,0.4) -- (0.325,0.7) -- (0.3,0.7) -- (0.3,0) -- (0.225,0) --
            (0.225,0.4) -- (0.175,0.4) -- (0.175,0) -- (0.1,0) -- (0.1,0.7) --
            (0.075,0.7) -- (0.075,0.4) -- cycle;
        \fill (0.2,0.9) circle (0.1);
        \coordinate (-head) at (0.2,1);
        \coordinate (-foot) at (0.2,0);
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic[red] at (0,2) (myman) {man};
\node[below=1mm of myman-foot] {Some text};
\node[above=1mm of myman-head] {Some text};

\pic[green] at (2,2) (greenman) {man};
\node[draw, above right=0pt of greenman-circ.60] {Some text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Can I also draw the circle around the man?

Comment: @Jamgreen I've updated the answer with a circular node around the man.