# Man running icon with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

I am a beginner in this. I am trying to prepare some exercises to my students in Latex. My main problem is the use of Tikz. In this case, I am trying to draw the icon of a man/woman running. I attach the picture of one quite simple.

Can you help me? Is there any way of converting a picture in other format to Tikz code?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you know you can simply include an image as node text?

Comment: Sorry , I do not know. How can I do this?

Comment: In your tikzpicture: `\node {\includegraphics{your-image}};`.

Comment: Strategies for including graphics in LaTeX documents https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb26-1/hoeppner.pdf

Comment: However, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so we can understand what is your desired result.

Comment: I do it in that way, the problem is that the background of this image is not transparent and the quality (it is a png) it is not very good. I am stating with the figure of the exercise and it is just a man running...

Comment: Well, drawing such a picture in TikZ is not easy and requires much effort.

Comment: Start from this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84275/custom-human-shape-for-tikz

Comment: Is this question about Tikz or pstricks, can you please clarify and either adjust the tags or the body of the question?

Comment: @Polygnome the question was about Tikz. [tag:pstricks] was not added by OP.

Comment: _It is nearly impossible to convert **all** images of all types to a TikZ picture code_. You said that you attached a _simple_ image, so I think you want to convert some more complex images. If the image is complex enough, I am sure that you must write hundreds lines of code to have it with great difficulty. So I suggest that you can find similar images on the Internet with `transparent background` keyword, and 99%-ly you will get the transparent image which you can insert in your document. For the running icon, I got [this picture](https://bit.ly/2w8salM) from [this](https://bit.ly/2ToX3dl).

Comment: If you make the picture by yourself, I think there should be a `transparent` option when you export it?

Comment: In the beginning he asked about TikZ. And there was no answer until I came with PSTricks answer. And as he accepted it, I added the PSTricks tag. It was the history.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

An attempt with `tikz` rectangles.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{body}= [fill=black,rounded corners=14pt]
    \draw[body,rotate around={35:(1.2,0)}] (1.2,0) rectangle ++(3.5,1) ;
    \draw[body,rotate around={75:(3.8,2)}] (3.8,2) rectangle ++(3,1) ;
    \draw[body,rotate around={-90:(6.25,6)},rounded corners=10pt] (6.25,6) rectangle ++(2,0.7) ;
    \draw[body,rotate around={-30:(6.2,4.2)},rounded corners=10pt] (6.2,4.2) rectangle ++(2.5,0.7) ;
    \draw[body,rotate around={7:(2.2,1.7)},draw=white,line width=4pt] (2.2,1.7) rectangle ++(3.7,1);
    \draw[body,rotate around={-52:(3.1,4.7)},draw=white,line width=2pt] (3.1,4.7) rectangle ++(3.5,1);
    \draw[body,rotate around={7:(2.2,1.7)}] (2.2,1.7) rectangle ++(3.7,1);
    \draw[body,rotate around={25:(3.7,3.7)},rounded corners=24pt] (3.7,3.7) rectangle ++(3.9,1.7);
    \draw[body,rotate around={145:(6.7,5.8)},rounded corners=10pt,draw=white,line width=2pt] (6.7,5.8) rectangle ++(2.3,0.7) ;
    \draw[body,rotate around={190:(5,7.1)},rounded corners=10pt] (5,7.1) rectangle ++(2.5,0.7);
    \draw[body] (8.2,6) circle (1cm);

    \draw[line width=2pt] (4.8,1) -- ++(2,0);
    \draw[line width=2pt] (6,1.3) -- ++(1.6,0);
    \draw[line width=2pt] (5.6,0.7) -- ++(1.6,0);

    \draw[line width=2pt] (0.5,5) -- ++(2,0);
    \draw[line width=2pt] (1.2,5.3) -- ++(1.6,0);
    \draw[line width=2pt] (1.1,4.7) -- ++(1.6,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### EDIT:

In order to properly scale this picture, use `[transform canvas={scale=0.2}]` with `tikzpicture` or `scope`. Read this answer also:[Correctly scaling a tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4345/28557).

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. The other answers use pstricks, while the question was about TikZ.

Comment: @clocktown Thanks for the appreciation. The question is tagged with both `pstricks` and `pgf-tikz` ;)

Comment: You are right, but then this is an example of a malformed question. If I ask a question about cats, but actually want to ask about cats and dogs, then I should but that in the title/body, not only in the tags.

Comment: @clocktown: That is a problem with the questian but _but_ not with the answers. And what answer will be accepted is a decision of the one who asked!

Comment: @Herbert you are right, however, I get the impression that the person asking the question really is a beginner, so he might not actually realise the difference. That is why I am writing this. He may not look back, and maybe he does know that it is not TikZ, but just in case he didn't know and comes back here, my comments could clear it up.

Comment: (+1) I like this one best too! It is the only one farting to increase speed. ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers. It is true that I do not understand the solution using pstricks. It is a way o easily rescale the solution. I need a man running 5 times smaller.

Comment: @EduardoYubero you can scale the picture by adding `scale` option. Replace `\begin{tikzpicture}` line with `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]`

Comment: Yes, but with this I resize the entire figure. If I have more things added the are scaled as well...

Comment: @Eduardo in that case you can wrap this code within `\begin{scope}[scale=0.2]` and `\end{scope}` and put inside `tikzpicture`. Read about `scope`.

Comment: @nidhin I have tried with \begin{scope} but the imaged is scaled but not in a proper way. The image is destroyed.

Comment: Good answer, what's the best way to get the exact coordinate? image is pixel but drawing is in cm or inch. how to map the pixel value to cm or inch?

Comment: @Eduardo Read this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4345. And try `\pgftransformscale`

Comment: @beetlej I don't know what you are looking for. pdftex supports using pixel (`px`). But one has to set its value properly. read: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41371/28557

Comment: @nidhin There is indeed the [pstricks] tag in the question, but if you see [this edit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/460560/revisions) you will notice that the tag is not tagged by the questian. At first the question is "Man running icon in Tikz"! So your answer is the best of course! (and I don't know why the edit is approved)

Comment: @nidhin thanks again!!! It works perfectly in the environment \pgflowlevelscope and \pgftransformscale. Now I have the image with the correct size. What do you recommend now to move the image? I am using this (\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}} ) but I am not sure it is the best option.

Comment: @nidhin I try \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1px,y=1px] but get error: unknow operator 'p' or 'px'. How you get the absolute position such as header position is (8.2,6) in your code?

Comment: @beetlej I inserted the image into `tikzpicture` and then drew grid. That gave the coordinates. ;)

Answer (score 11):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\def\wind{%
    \psline[linewidth=0.2](8,-9)(11,-9)
    \psline[linewidth=0.2](5,-9.4)(10,-9.4)
    \psline[linewidth=0.2](7,-9.8)(10.5,-9.8)}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[linecap=1,linejoin=1](-1,-12)(13,3)
    \psframe[fillstyle=vlines,hatchangle=-45,hatchsep=.3,hatchcolor=lightgray](-1,-12)(13,3)
    \qdisk(11,-0.5){1.5}
    \psline[linewidth=1.5](4,-4)(3,-7)(1,-10)
    \psline[linewidth=1.75,linecolor=white](3.5,-4)(6,-7)(1,-7)
    \psline[linewidth=1.5](3.5,-4)(6,-7)(1,-7)
    \psline[linewidth=2.5](8,-1)(4.1,-3.8)
    \psline[linewidth=1](8,-1)(8,-4)(11,-5)
    \psline[linewidth=1.25,linecolor=white](8,-1)(6,2)(3,1)
    \psline[linewidth=1](8,-1)(6,2)(3,1)
    \wind
    \rput(-5.5,9){\wind}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice picture! Sadly `pstricks` is not what the OP wants :(

Comment: ...nevertheless not a reason to downvote imho (+1), all the more the OP didn't even provide a MWE to fix or complete.

Comment: @DũngVũ Please have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3458/36296 Even if pstricks is not asked for in the question, seeing a variate of answers will benefit future users of this site

Answer (score 9):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\def\wind{%
    \psline[linewidth=0.2](8,-9)(11,-9)
    \psline[linewidth=0.2](5,-9.4)(10,-9.4)
    \psline[linewidth=0.2](7,-9.8)(10.5,-9.8)}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[linecap=1,linejoin=1](-1,-12)(13,3)
    \psframe[fillstyle=vlines,hatchangle=-45,hatchsep=.3,hatchcolor=lightgray](-1,-12)(13,3)
    \qdisk(11,-0.5){1.5}
    \psline[linewidth=2.5](8,-1)(4,-4)
    \psline[linewidth=1.5](4,-4)(3,-7)(1,-10)
    \psline[linewidth=1.5](3.75,-4.25)(6,-7)(1,-7)
    \psline[linewidth=1](8,-1)(8,-4)(11,-5)
    \psline[linewidth=1](8,-1)(6,2)(3,1)
    \wind
    \rput(-5.5,9){\wind}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: one downvote detected...

Comment: This is pstricks. He asked for TikZ.

Comment: @clocktown: But he loves PSTricks answer.

Comment: Yes, but it's technically not a correct answer. Although I love it too (its shorter compared to the TikZ answer). But as he says he is teaching, when he teaches TikZ, he shouldn't come up with pstricks. Could be confusing.

Comment: One more downvote detected.

Comment: but always no need vor downvoting!

Comment: @clocktown: This site is not meant for just one person to get an answer to a particular problem. If someone comes across this need, but in `pstricks`, should they post another question? Just because it is not directly helpful to the OP, this a perfectly valid answer.  IMHO, a downvote should be reserved for answers which do not address the question, or for ones in which the answer may have other major issues (even if they don't show up in code provided).

Comment: BTW, the above comment was meant for the down-voter, not saying it was you. Just because you provided a possible reason for the downvote, I didn't want to make an assumption here.

Answer (score 9):

Similar to [nidhin's one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/460576/1952) but drawn with thick lines with round caps instead of rectangles:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    myline/.style={%
        line cap=round, 
        line join=round,
        line width=#1}]
    \draw[myline=10mm] (1.2,0.65) -- (3.25,2)--(3.9,4.5);
    \draw[preaction={draw, myline=12mm, white}, myline=11mm] (3.95,4.6) -- (5.25,2.5)--(2.5,2.25);
    \draw[myline=7mm] (6.6,5.7) -- (6.6,4.35)--(8.25,3.35);
    \draw[myline=18mm] (4.2,4.85)--(6.1,5.75);
    \draw[preaction={draw, myline=8mm, white}, myline=7mm] (6.2,5.8) -- (4.8,6.75)--(3,6.4);
    \fill (8.1,6) circle(1cm);
    \draw[myline=2pt] (4.8,1) -- ++(2,0);
    \draw[myline=2pt] (6,1.3) -- ++(1.6,0);
    \draw[myline=2pt] (5.6,0.7) -- ++(1.6,0);

    \draw[myline=2pt] (0.5,5) -- ++(2,0);
    \draw[myline=2pt] (1.2,5.3) -- ++(1.6,0);
    \draw[myline=2pt] (1.1,4.7) -- ++(1.6,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A similar pictogram to the one you show in your question is available as vector image from https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/Running_icon_-_Noun_Project_17825.svg

This opens a couple of possibilities:

1. use the `svg` package to include the graphic (needs shell-escape to compile and inkscape installed)
2. Use and external program like inkscape to convert the graphic to pdf, which then can be included with `\includegraphics` in your document
3. Convert the .svg to tikz, which can for example be done with inkscape:

---

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill (2.7298,2.9966) .. controls (2.6046,2.9966) and (2.5032,2.8951) .. (2.5032,2.7702) .. controls (2.5032,2.6453) and (2.6046,2.5438) .. (2.7298,2.5438) .. controls (2.8547,2.5438) and (2.9560,2.6453) .. (2.9560,2.7702) .. controls (2.9560,2.8952) and (2.8547,2.9966) .. (2.7298,2.9966) -- cycle(1.8120,2.9130) .. controls (1.7960,2.9125) and (1.7807,2.9106) .. (1.7674,2.9074) -- (1.3128,2.7960) .. controls (1.2596,2.7830) and (1.2161,2.7320) .. (1.2161,2.6827) .. controls (1.2161,2.6333) and (1.2596,2.6035) .. (1.3129,2.6163) -- (1.7107,2.7116) .. controls (1.7640,2.7244) and (1.8460,2.7118) .. (1.8930,2.6837) -- (2.0218,2.6065) .. controls (2.0689,2.5784) and (2.0689,2.5322) .. (2.0221,2.5037) -- (1.6233,2.2623) .. controls (1.5764,2.2339) and (1.5162,2.1788) .. (1.4894,2.1396) .. controls (1.4626,2.1006) and (1.5647,1.8858) .. (1.5882,1.8363) -- (1.7125,1.5730) .. controls (1.7360,1.5235) and (1.7103,1.4815) .. (1.6555,1.4815) -- (1.1510,1.4815) .. controls (1.0962,1.4815) and (1.0551,1.4383) .. (1.0596,1.3837) -- (1.0660,1.3196) .. controls (1.0704,1.2650) and (1.1189,1.2345) .. (1.1738,1.2345) -- (2.0524,1.2345) .. controls (2.1071,1.2345) and (2.1361,1.2629) .. (2.1166,1.3142) -- (1.9628,1.7126) .. controls (1.9433,1.7638) and (1.9151,1.8455) .. (1.9002,1.8982) -- (1.8951,1.9147) .. controls (1.8801,1.9674) and (1.9066,2.0323) .. (1.9539,2.0599) -- (2.2306,2.2209) .. controls (2.2779,2.2485) and (2.3414,2.2829) .. (2.3717,2.2977) .. controls (2.4020,2.3125) and (2.4391,2.2815) .. (2.4541,2.2287) -- (2.5489,1.8960) .. controls (2.5638,1.8433) and (2.6199,1.8096) .. (2.6734,1.8212) -- (3.2002,1.9352) .. controls (3.2537,1.9468) and (3.2975,1.9933) .. (3.2975,2.0386) .. controls (3.2975,2.0839) and (3.2531,2.1140) .. (3.1990,2.1056) -- (2.8194,2.0463) .. controls (2.7653,2.0379) and (2.7083,2.0740) .. (2.6930,2.1265) -- (2.5884,2.4840) .. controls (2.5730,2.5365) and (2.5205,2.5997) .. (2.4716,2.6244) -- (1.9532,2.8861) .. controls (1.9165,2.9046) and (1.8603,2.9147) .. (1.8120,2.9130) -- cycle(0.4593,2.4347) .. controls (0.4045,2.4347) and (0.3596,2.4167) .. (0.3596,2.3994) .. controls (0.3596,2.3821) and (0.4045,2.3641) .. (0.4593,2.3641) -- (1.5070,2.3641) .. controls (1.5618,2.3641) and (1.6067,2.3821) .. (1.6067,2.3994) .. controls (1.6067,2.4167) and (1.5618,2.4347) .. (1.5070,2.4347) -- cycle(0.5811,2.2935) .. controls (0.5263,2.2935) and (0.4815,2.2755) .. (0.4815,2.2582) .. controls (0.4815,2.2409) and (0.5263,2.2229) .. (0.5811,2.2229) -- (1.3545,2.2229) .. controls (1.4092,2.2229) and (1.4542,2.2409) .. (1.4542,2.2582) .. controls (1.4542,2.2755) and (1.4093,2.2935) .. (1.3545,2.2935) -- cycle(0.6622,2.1523) .. controls (0.6074,2.1523) and (0.5626,2.1342) .. (0.5626,2.1170) .. controls (0.5626,2.0997) and (0.6075,2.0817) .. (0.6622,2.0817) -- (1.3041,2.0817) .. controls (1.3588,2.0817) and (1.4037,2.0997) .. (1.4037,2.1170) .. controls (1.4037,2.1342) and (1.3588,2.1523) .. (1.3041,2.1523) -- cycle(1.5539,1.1639) .. controls (1.4991,1.1639) and (1.4177,1.1442) .. (1.3730,1.1125) -- (1.1237,0.9389) .. controls (1.0790,0.9072) and (1.0684,0.8463) .. (1.1001,0.8016) -- (1.1495,0.7328) .. controls (1.1812,0.6881) and (1.2422,0.6799) .. (1.2851,0.7140) -- (1.7881,1.1079) .. controls (1.8309,1.1420) and (1.8211,1.1639) .. (1.7663,1.1639) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]