# Custom "computer" resp. "server" shape for tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

Similar to the [custom "human" shape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84275/custom-human-shape-for-tikz) resp. the [tikzpeople package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpeople) I'm now looking for nice computer shapes. I'm drawing some diagram showing the collaboration and communication of humans through some server infrastructure. Is there maybe some package for such shapes similar to tikzpeople?

Maybe something like these:

[image: from Nuvola icon theme for KDE 3.x / GNOME 2.]
[image] [by Mimooh](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Server2_by_mimooh.svg)

or it can also be as sophisticated as these

[image: https://www.freeiconspng.com/images/server-icons]

So far I could only find this one from [texample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/network-topology/) resp. [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158860/11820) but this doesn't really satisfy me.

[image]

```
% Three-tier data center architecture
% Author: Claudio Fiandrino
% from http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/network-topology/ resp. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158860/11820
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,shadings,shapes.arrows,shapes.symbols,shadows}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/pgf/.cd,
  parallelepiped offset x/.initial=2mm,
  parallelepiped offset y/.initial=2mm
}
\pgfdeclareshape{parallelepiped}
{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is nearly a rectangle
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
  \backgroundpath{
    % store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdima{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/parallelepiped
      offset x}}
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/parallelepiped
      offset y}}
    \def\ppd@offset{\pgfpoint{\pgfutil@tempdima}{\pgfutil@tempdimb}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}{\ppd@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}
  }
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{
  ports/.style={
    line width=0.3pt,
    top color=gray!20,
    bottom color=gray!80
  },
  server/.style={
    parallelepiped,
    fill=white, draw,
    minimum width=0.35cm,
    minimum height=0.75cm,
    parallelepiped offset x=3mm,
    parallelepiped offset y=2mm,
    xscale=-1,
    path picture={
      \draw[top color=gray!5,bottom color=gray!40]
      (path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle 
      (path picture bounding box.north east);
      \coordinate (A-center) at ($(path picture bounding box.center)!0!(path
        picture bounding box.south)$);
      \coordinate (A-west) at ([xshift=-0.575cm]path picture bounding box.west);
      \draw[ports]([yshift=0.1cm]$(A-west)!0!(A-center)$)
        rectangle +(0.2,0.065);
      \draw[ports]([yshift=0.01cm]$(A-west)!0.085!(A-center)$)
        rectangle +(0.15,0.05);
      \fill[black]([yshift=-0.35cm]$(A-west)!-0.1!(A-center)$)
        rectangle +(0.235,0.0175);
      \fill[black]([yshift=-0.385cm]$(A-west)!-0.1!(A-center)$)
        rectangle +(0.235,0.0175);
      \fill[black]([yshift=-0.42cm]$(A-west)!-0.1!(A-center)$)
        rectangle +(0.235,0.0175);
    }  
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[server](server 1){};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The shape unfortunately is not scalable using e.g. `minimum size=1.5cm`.

Edit: it is scalable using `scale=1.5` and also `shape transform`. But still this server does not look the best ;-)

Comment: By default, nodes are insensitive to transformations, you must add the`transform shape` option :  `\node[server,scale=1.5,transform shape](server 1){};`

Comment: Cool `\node[server,scale=1.5](server 1){};` does it already. What is the `transform shape` responsible for?

Comment: `transform shape` allow to apply transformations to `node`

Comment: There is no need to use the `parallelepiped` shape if you do not use its anchors. A simple `pic` would do. Also be aware that `transform shape` does not transform line widths.

Comment: Since this one doesn't suit you, what is the symbol you are waiting for? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: I've added some examples

Comment: All the pictures you have added are projections of 3d objects with or without perspective. The `parallelepiped` is not any such projection. If you wish to have a real projection, look at section **63 Three Point Perspective Drawing Library** of the pgfmanual v3.1.4b. If you do not want perspective, `tikz-3dplot` is a great tool. You could store the result in a `\savebox`. Then using `scale` in the nodes containing the `\savebox`es is enough. no `transform shape` is needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct key to scale nodes is, unsurprisingly, `scale`. `transform shape` is only necessary if the transformations are set outside a node option, e.g. in a scope, and the pgf manual is very clear about this. (I do not see it as the purpose of this site to literally copy from the pgf manual and paste here unless it is something that usually gets overlooked.) Your desired pictures are 3d-like, i.e. they seem to be obtained through an orthogonal projection of some 3d picture. This answer gives you a start. The result can be conveniently stored in `\savebox`es, which can be used in nodes, and of course be scaled and/or transformed otherwise.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\newsavebox\Server
\sbox\Server{\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{20}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=3]
  \path (1,0)  coordinate(aux);
  \path (1pt,0) coordinate (BTL) (1cm-1pt,0) coordinate (BTR)
  (1cm,-2.5cm+1pt) coordinate (BBR) (1cm,-1pt) coordinate (BTR');
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
  \draw[rounded corners={2*sqrt(2)*1pt},fill=gray!10] (0,-2.5) rectangle (1,0);
  \draw[rounded corners={2*sqrt(2)*1pt},white] (0.4pt,-2.5cm+0.4pt) 
    rectangle (1cm-0.4pt,0-0.4pt);
  \path (1pt,0) coordinate (FTL) (1cm-1pt,0) coordinate (FTR);
  \path[fill=white,rounded corners={2*sqrt(2)*1pt}]
   ($(aux)+(-1,0)$) -| ++(1,-2.5) -- (1,-2.5) |- (0,0)--cycle;
  \path[left color=gray!10,right color=gray!30,rounded corners=1pt] (BTL) -- (BTR) -- (FTR) -- (FTL)
    -- cycle;
  \path[top color=gray!80,bottom color=gray!30,shading angle=20,
    rounded corners=1pt]
   (1cm,-2.5cm+1pt) -- (BBR) -- (BTR') -- (1cm,-1pt) -- cycle;
  \draw[ultra thin,fill=gray!40] foreach \X in {0.2,0.3,...,0.81} 
  { \foreach \Y in {-0.2,-0.3,...,-2.3} 
   {(\X-0.03,\Y-0.03) rectangle (\X+0.03,\Y+0.03)}};
  \begin{scope} 
   \clip (0,-2.5) rectangle (1,-0.6pt);
   \fill[gray!10] (0.5,0) circle[radius=0.35cm];
   \shade[ball color=black!80] (0.5,0) circle[radius=0.25cm];
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[rounded corners=1mm] 
   \clip (0.42,-0.7) -- (0.42,-0.9) -- (0.22,-1.1)
    -- (0.42,-1.3) -- (0.42,-2.1) -- (0.58,-2.1) 
    -- (0.58,-1.3) -- (0.78,-1.1) -- (0.58,-0.9) -- (0.58,-0.7) -- cycle;
   \fill[gray!80] (0.42,-0.7) -- (0.42,-0.9) -- (0.22,-1.1)
    -- (0.42,-1.3) -- (0.42,-2.1) -- (0.58,-2.1) 
    -- (0.58,-1.3) -- (0.78,-1.1) -- (0.58,-0.9) -- (0.58,-0.7) -- cycle;
   \fill[gray!20] (0.03+0.42,-0.7) -- (0.03+0.42,-0.9) -- (0.03+0.22,-1.1)
    -- (0.03+0.42,-1.3) -- (0.03+0.42,-2.1) -- (0.03+0.58,-2.1) 
    -- (0.03+0.58,-1.3) -- (0.03+0.78,-1.1) -- (0.03+0.58,-0.9) -- (0.03+0.58,-0.7) -- cycle;       
  \end{scope} 
  \shade[ball color=black!80] (0.5,-1.1) circle[radius=0.1cm];
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node (server1){\usebox\Server};
 \node[right=2cm of server1,scale=2] (server2){\usebox\Server};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The neat thing about this is that, unlike when loading an external graphics, you can adjust the view angles. For instance, if you change the phi angle, i.e. the second argument of `\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{<phi>}`, you get

[image]

It goes without saying that these are vector graphics, i.e. there is no loss of quality if you zoom in.

Comment: Is it also possible to define this as a new shape?

Comment: @white_gecko Short answer: no. This is because, as of now, node anchors are two-dimensional objects, i.e. only have two coordinates. On the other hand, you only benefit from a specialized shape if you make use of its anchors. The nodes `server1` and `server2` still have the anchors of the rectangle node that wraps the `\savebox`es like `west` and so on, but nothing more than that. You *can* use a pic and add anchor-like coordinates as in the example on top of p. 263 of pgfmanual v3.1.4b.

Answer (score 4):

I quote the 3.1.4b manual page 241:

> **Transformations**
>
> It is possible to transform nodes, but, by default, transformations do
> not apply to nodes. The reason is that you usually do not want your
> text to be scaled or rotated even if the main graphic is transformed.
> Scaling text is evil, rotating slightly less so.
>
> [...]
>
> **/tikz/transform shape (no value)** Causes the current “external” transformation matrix to be applied to the shape.

[image: screenshot]

```
% Three-tier data center architecture
% Author: Claudio Fiandrino
% from http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/network-topology/ resp. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158860/11820
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,shadings,shapes.arrows,shapes.symbols,shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/pgf/.cd,
  parallelepiped offset x/.initial=2mm,
  parallelepiped offset y/.initial=2mm
}
\pgfdeclareshape{parallelepiped}
{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is nearly a rectangle
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
  \backgroundpath{
    % store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdima{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/parallelepiped
      offset x}}
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdimb{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/parallelepiped
      offset y}}
    \def\ppd@offset{\pgfpoint{\pgfutil@tempdima}{\pgfutil@tempdimb}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}{\ppd@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}{\ppd@offset}}
  }
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{
  ports/.style={
    line width=0.3pt,
    top color=gray!20,
    bottom color=gray!80
  },
  server/.style={
    parallelepiped,
    fill=white, draw,
    minimum width=0.35cm,
    minimum height=0.75cm,
    parallelepiped offset x=3mm,
    parallelepiped offset y=2mm,
    xscale=-1,
    path picture={
      \draw[top color=gray!5,bottom color=gray!40]
      (path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle 
      (path picture bounding box.north east);
      \coordinate (A-center) at ($(path picture bounding box.center)!0!(path
        picture bounding box.south)$);
      \coordinate (A-west) at ([xshift=-0.575cm]path picture bounding box.west);
      \draw[ports]([yshift=0.1cm]$(A-west)!0!(A-center)$)
        rectangle +(0.2,0.065);
      \draw[ports]([yshift=0.01cm]$(A-west)!0.085!(A-center)$)
        rectangle +(0.15,0.05);
      \fill[black]([yshift=-0.35cm]$(A-west)!-0.1!(A-center)$)
        rectangle +(0.235,0.0175);
      \fill[black]([yshift=-0.385cm]$(A-west)!-0.1!(A-center)$)
        rectangle +(0.235,0.0175);
      \fill[black]([yshift=-0.42cm]$(A-west)!-0.1!(A-center)$)
        rectangle +(0.235,0.0175);
    }  
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[server](server 1){};

\node[server,scale=1.5,right =2cm of server 1](server 2){};

\node[server,scale=4,right =4cm of server 2](server 3){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `transform shape` is irrelevant here. The same result is obtained if you drop this key. What is relevant is the `scale` key. `transform shape` is relevant if one defines the transformations in a scope (or similar).

Comment: As it stands the quote in the answer is a bit confusing: you've got `transform shape` there but have (as suggested above) removed it from your actual code. It would be sensible to point out in the answer that the key does not work here.

Comment: @JosephWright Perhaps "the key does not work here" should really read "the key is not needed here". This key "works", but is needed (and useful) only if one wants to apply “external” transformations, i.e. transformations that appear in the options of the `tikzpicture` or an ambient `scope`. A node will always apply the transformations that are contained in its options, such as `scale`, `rotate` and so on. This is also why one should *not* add `transform shape` just so: in a more complex setting you may pick up a transformation that you did not want to apply.