# Determine hex unicode character code from raw character?

Tags: graphics, pdftex, unicode, font-encodings, extended-characters

I found [coloremoji](https://github.com/doraTeX/coloremoji) which allows inserting apple's color emoji's into an *uptex* document. This library first extracts all emoji's as PDFs named according to their hex unicode character codes (e.g. 1F36E.pdf). Then there is a stylesheet (coloremoji.sty) which seemingly looks up an incoming emoji's hex code and includes the corresponding PDF.

However, this seems to require some upTeX specific features. I'd like to get this working with `pdflatex` using `\usepackage{stringenc}`,`\usepackage{utf8}`,`\usepackage{fontenc}`, etc.

Is this possible to look up a raw unicode character's hex code using pdflatex (TeXLive on Mac OS X)?

Here's the imagined interface (as a screenshot to preserve emoji)[image]

The `coloremoji` command should expand to an `includegraphics` so that the resulting document is a cheeseburger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have already the converted PDF files, here's a version that works with all engines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,stringenc}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_const:Nn \c_coloremoji_dir_tl { ./emoji_images/hires }
\tl_new:N \l_coloremoji_input_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \coloremoji_unicode:nn #1 #2
 {
  \includegraphics[#1]{\c_coloremoji_dir_tl / \int_to_Hex:n{`#2}.pdf}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \coloremoji_eightbit:nn #1 #2
 {
  \StringEncodingConvert \l_coloremoji_input_tl
    { \tl_to_str:n { #2 } } { utf8 } { utf32 }
  \tl_set:Nx \l_coloremoji_input_tl { \pdfescapehex\expandafter{\l_coloremoji_input_tl} }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \A 0* } { } \l_coloremoji_input_tl
  \includegraphics[#1]{\c_coloremoji_dir_tl / \l_coloremoji_input_tl.pdf}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\coloremoji}{O{}m}
 {
  \bool_if:nTF { \xetex_if_engine_p: || \luatex_if_engine_p: }
   {
    \coloremoji_unicode:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
  {
   \coloremoji_eightbit:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\coloremoji{}

\end{document}
```

Compile with `pdflatex`, XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Change the meaning of `\c_coloremoji_dir_tl` to point to the directory where the PDF files are.

---

This is a `pdftex` only solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringenc,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gethex}[1]{%
  \StringEncodingConvert{\gh@tmp}{\detokenize{#1}}{utf8}{utf32}%
  \edef\gh@tmp{\pdfescapehex\expandafter{\gh@tmp}}%
  \expandafter\get@hex\gh@tmp\get@hex
}
\def\get@hex#1{%
  \if0#1%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\get@hex}{\get@hex@aux#1}%
}
\def\get@hex@aux#1\get@hex{%
   \def\gh@string{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\coloremoji}[2][]{%
  \gethex{#2}%
  \includegraphics[#1]{./emoji_images/hires/\gh@string.pdf}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\coloremoji{}

\end{document}
```

---

A version without `stringenc` that works with all engines. Note that the argument to `\coloremoji` must be a ***single*** Unicode character. The `\newunicodechar` part is just to show compatibility. The optional argument to `\coloremoji` is passed to `\includegraphics`.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not necessary, but recommended if pdflatex is used
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{}{\coloremoji{}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\coloremoji}{O{}m}
 {
  \coloremoji_unicode:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

%%% the location where the images are found
\tl_const:Nn \c_coloremoji_dir_tl { ./emoji_images/hires }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \coloremoji_unicode:nn #1 #2
 {
  \includegraphics[#1]{\c_coloremoji_dir_tl / \manual_get_hex:n { #2 }.pdf}
 }

\cs_new:Npn \manual_get_hex_unicode:n #1
 {
  \int_to_Hex:n { `#1 }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \manual_utfviii_to_unicode:n #1
 {
  \tl_if_blank:oTF { \tl_to_str:n { #1 } }
   { 20 }
   { \__manual_utfviii_to_unicode_aux:o { \tl_to_str:n { #1 } } }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \__manual_utfviii_to_unicode_aux:n #1
 {
  \int_case:nn { \tl_count:n { #1 } }
   {
    {1}{ \int_to_Hex:n { `#1 } }
    {2}{ \__manual_utfviii_twobyte:f { #1 } }
    {3}{ \__manual_utfviii_threebyte:f { #1 } }
    {4}{ \__manual_utfviii_fourbyte:f { #1 } }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__manual_utfviii_to_unicode_aux:n { o }

\cs_new:Npn \__manual_utfviii_twobyte:n #1
 {
  \__manual_utfviii_twobyte_aux:nn #1
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__manual_utfviii_twobyte:n { f }

\cs_new:Npn \__manual_utfviii_twobyte_aux:nn #1 #2
 {
  \int_to_Hex:n { (`#1-192)*64 + (`#2-128) }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \__manual_utfviii_threebyte:n #1
 {
  \__manual_utfviii_threebyte_aux:nnn #1
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__manual_utfviii_threebyte:n { f }

\cs_new:Npn \__manual_utfviii_threebyte_aux:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \int_to_Hex:n { (`#1-224)*4096 + (`#2-128)*64 + (`#3-128) }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \__manual_utfviii_fourbyte:n #1
 {
  \__manual_utfviii_fourbyte_aux:nnnn #1
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__manual_utfviii_fourbyte:n { f }

\cs_new:Npn \__manual_utfviii_fourbyte_aux:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
 {
  \int_to_Hex:n { (`#1-240)*262144 + (`#2-128)*4096 + (`#3-128)*64 + (`#4-128) }
 }

\bool_if:nTF { \xetex_if_engine_p: || \luatex_if_engine_p: }
 {
  \cs_set_eq:NN \manual_get_hex:n \manual_get_hex_unicode:n
 }
 {
  \cs_set_eq:NN \manual_get_hex:n \manual_utfviii_to_unicode:n
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\coloremoji{}

\coloremoji[width=1cm]{}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. This is a now a working, workaround for the true problem of directly including the apple emoji font and displaying emojis as glyphs: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88305/emoji-characters Any thoughts on that one?

Comment: @mangledorf Use `\coloremoji{...}`

Comment: I understand that. But that's just including the PDF, rather than rendering the character using the apple color emoji font (relying on viewer support of course).

Comment: @mangledorf I don't see how XeTeX or LuaTeX can support the font, as it works by embedding a PDF file. One could emulate it with `newunicodechar` by doing `\newunicodechar{}{\coloremoji{}}`, but this needs knowing the characters one wants to use.

Comment: ooh burger time! `:)`