# create latex symbol from vector graphics

Tags: graphics, symbols

I have a logo in vector format (Adobe Illustrator) that I would like to use in my LaTeX documents. How do I create a latex symbol such that I can include this logo inline with the text, similarly to the symbol \LaTeX for example:

[image]

**UPDATE**

My logo contains a 'y' character and the solution outlined works but the baselines do not match (as the logo baseline is the bottom of 'y'). So I fixed it this way:

```
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\mylogo{\kern0em\raise-.1667em\hbox{\scalerel*{\includegraphics{mylogo.pdf}}{X}}}
```

**UPDATE 2**

An update on the answer seems to be a better way of accomplishing this.

Comment: Metapost? Or include the symbol as a graphic.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

See UPDATE below, for graphics with descenders.

Here, `\scalerel*` scales the image to take the same vertical footprint as a capital letter "X".   That also means the logo will automatically scale with font size.  EDITED to make the process a macro (thanks to Maarten).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\mylogo{\scalerel*{\includegraphics{ARL_Logo_March2012_BlackGold}}{X}}
\begin{document}
Can I insert my \mylogo{} inline?

\tiny Can I insert my \mylogo{} inline?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Because the original was a vector image stored in PDF, it zooms without loss of resolution:

[image]

UPDATE:

If the original graphic has descenders, one has two options.

One can vertically shift (with a `\raisebox`) the `\includegraphics` to match the natural baseline of the graphic with the LaTeX baseline and then "fool" `\scalerel*` but turning off the depth of shifted graphic:

```
\documentclass{article}
\fboxsep=-\fboxrule
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\theirlogo{\scalerel*{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\raisebox{-52pt}{\includegraphics{GoogleLogo}}}\dp0=0pt\box0}{X}}
\begin{document}
Can I insert my \theirlogo{} inline?

\tiny Can I insert my \theirlogo{} inline?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately (and perhaps more efficiently), one could leave the `\includegraphics` unaltered and add a appropriately sized negative rule (in scalable units) to the second argument of the `\scalerel*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\fboxsep=-\fboxrule
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\theirlogo{\scalerel*{\includegraphics{GoogleLogo}}{X\rule[-.6ex]{0pt}{1pt}}}
\begin{document}
Can I insert my \theirlogo{} inline?

\tiny Can I insert my \theirlogo{} inline?
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using this solution you could easily create your Latex symbol (command) by putting `\newcommand{\mylogo}{\scalerel*{\includegraphics{ARL_Logo_March2012_BlackGold}}{X}\ }` in the preamble. Now you can use the command `\mylogo` wherever you want inside your document.

Comment: @MaartenDhondt Yes, that would be recommended.  I shall revise my MWE to reflect that.

Comment: Yes @StevenB.Segletes, do it so that your answer is complete.

Comment: @aaragon I believe that such an edit has already been made, so that `\mylogo{}` is all that need appear in the document itself, now that it is defined in the preamble.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes he doesn't use braces.

Comment: @aaragon Your original question asked for it to be like `\LaTeX`, and that uses braces, as in `\LaTeX{}`.  The reason that is a preferred solution is that if I add a space inside the macro, as did Maarten, then I can't use the macro immediately before punctuation, such as `,` or `.` because a space will be inserted.  This closing `{}` brace approach is considered preferable because of its flexibility with punctuation.  You get used to it.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes got it! Thanks again, it's a great solution.

Comment: @aaragon See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31091/space-after-latex-commands, for example, for more discussion of this issue.  And lest you think `xspace` is an alternative, see this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace.

Comment: My logo has a 'y' letter in it, so the baseline of the characters do not align (it's as if the bottom of the 'character' is the baseline for the logo). Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: @aaragon Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why do not use

```
\def\mylogo{{\includegraphics[height=1.4ex]{ARL_Logo_March2012_BlackGold}}}
\begin{document}
Can I insert my \mylogo{} inline?
```

ex is the height of the "x" character, and changes with the font size.