# Writing Google logo in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, graphics, symbols

This is very hard to google itself. I have been told it is possible to use the `Google` logo in regular text in LaTeX, but I'm struggling to find out how.

For example:

```
Some words, then {Google Logo here} and then so on...
```

Comment: Do you know the font used on it? You can insert the logo as an image. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_logo#/media/File:Google_2015_logo.svg

Comment: The font itself isn't made public by google, http://designforhackers.com/blog/googles-new-logo-font/

Comment: always for company logos best just to use the  image rather than try to fake it with similar fonts, eg the logo today at least is https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png

Comment: Is there a way to add an image directly to the actual title of a document?

Comment: yes of course you can just use `\includegraphics{...}`

Comment: Never understand why such questions gather lot of likes in http://tex.stackexchange.com/. Wouldn't be easer to use `\includegrahics`? What is motivation of ignoring `\includegrahics`?

Answer (score 46):

## Image-based approach

The scaling is not perfect, but it's pretty close. The basic idea is to set the height of the image to the sum of the height of `G` and the depth of `g` in the current font. Then lower the image by the depth of `g` to attempt to align the baseline.

Unfortunately, this method is dependent on the descender depth and capital height of the logo font relative to those of the font in use in the TeX document. Slight tweaks might be required. I downloaded the logo as an SVG image and converted it to PDF for use with `\includegraphics`.

The `\protected\def` is so that the command can be used in moving arguments. If `hyperref` is used, you might also want `\texorpdfstring` or similar for bookmarks/etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc,graphicx}
\newlength\htG\newlength\dpg
\protected\def\google{\settoheight{\htG}{G}\settodepth{\dpg}{g}%
  \raisebox{-\dpg}{\includegraphics[height=\htG+\dpg]{Google_2015_logo}}}

\title{\google\ in the title}
\author{A \google r}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{\google\ in a section}
\google\ all around!
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

## SVG path approach (with *Star Wars*-inspired testing code)

Alternative to the image-based approach, we can use Ti*k*Z's `svg.path` library and borrow the paths for each letter directly from Google's SVG file. This allows us to set the baseline more precisely at the bottom of the "l"'s rectangle (which is why it's drawn first). The main ideas are quite similar to the original method, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\definecolor{gG}{RGB}{ 60, 186,  84}
\definecolor{gY}{RGB}{244, 194,  13}
\definecolor{gB}{RGB}{ 72, 133, 237}
\definecolor{gR}{RGB}{219,  50,  54}

\newlength\htG
\protected\def\google{\settoheight{\htG}{G}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1,scale=(\htG/240pt),baseline=(baseline)]
    \fill[fill=gG] svg {m797.49 249.7h35.975v-240.75h-35.975z};
    \coordinate (baseline) at (current bounding box.south);
    \fill[fill=gB] svg {m246.11 116.18h-116.57v34.591h82.673c-4.0842 48.506-44.44 69.192-82.533 69.192-48.736 0-91.264-38.346-91.264-92.092 0-52.357 40.54-92.679 91.371-92.679 39.217 0 62.326 25 62.326 25l24.22-25.081s-31.087-34.608-87.784-34.608c-72.197-0.001-128.05 60.933-128.05 126.75 0 64.493 52.539 127.38 129.89 127.38 68.031 0 117.83-46.604 117.83-115.52 0-14.539-2.1109-22.942-2.1109-22.942z};
    \fill[fill=gR] svg {m341.6 91.129c-47.832 0-82.111 37.395-82.111 81.008 0 44.258 33.249 82.348 82.673 82.348 44.742 0 81.397-34.197 81.397-81.397 0-54.098-42.638-81.959-81.959-81.959zm0.47563 32.083c23.522 0 45.812 19.017 45.812 49.66 0 29.993-22.195 49.552-45.92 49.552-26.068 0-46.633-20.878-46.633-49.79 0-28.292 20.31-49.422 46.741-49.422z};
    \fill[fill=gY] svg {m520.18 91.129c-47.832 0-82.111 37.395-82.111 81.008 0 44.258 33.249 82.348 82.673 82.348 44.742 0 81.397-34.197 81.397-81.397 0-54.098-42.638-81.959-81.959-81.959zm0.47562 32.083c23.522 0 45.812 19.017 45.812 49.66 0 29.993-22.195 49.552-45.92 49.552-26.068 0-46.633-20.878-46.633-49.79 0-28.292 20.31-49.422 46.741-49.422z};
    \fill[fill=gB] svg {m695.34 91.215c-43.904 0-78.414 38.453-78.414 81.613 0 49.163 40.009 81.765 77.657 81.765 23.279 0 35.657-9.2405 44.796-19.847v16.106c0 28.18-17.11 45.055-42.936 45.055-24.949 0-37.463-18.551-41.812-29.078l-31.391 13.123c11.136 23.547 33.554 48.103 73.463 48.103 43.652 0 76.922-27.495 76.922-85.159v-146.77h-34.245v13.836c-10.53-11.347-24.93-18.745-44.04-18.745zm3.178 32.018c21.525 0 43.628 18.38 43.628 49.768 0 31.904-22.056 49.487-44.104 49.487-23.406 0-45.185-19.005-45.185-49.184 0-31.358 22.619-50.071 45.66-50.071z};
    \fill[fill=gR] svg {m925.89 91.02c-41.414 0-76.187 32.95-76.187 81.57 0 51.447 38.759 81.959 80.165 81.959 34.558 0 55.768-18.906 68.426-35.845l-28.235-18.787c-7.3268 11.371-19.576 22.484-40.018 22.484-22.962 0-33.52-12.574-40.061-24.754l109.52-45.444-5.6859-13.318c-10.58-26.08-35.26-47.86-67.92-47.86zm1.4268 31.413c14.923 0 25.663 7.9342 30.224 17.447l-73.139 30.57c-3.1532-23.667 19.269-48.017 42.915-48.017z};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

% just for the testing section
\newcommand{\testing}[1]{\noindent\leavevmode#1\rlap{G}\google\llap{e} \quad \rlap{Google}\google \qquad \google\llap{Google}\par}

\title{\google\ in the title}
\author{A \google r}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{\google\ in a section}
\google\ all around! 

\section{Some testing code}
\testing{\tiny}
\testing{\scriptsize}
\testing{\footnotesize}
\testing{\small}
\testing{\normalsize}
\testing{\large}
\testing{\Large}
\testing{\LARGE}
\testing{\huge}
\testing{\Huge}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 25):

Do you mean this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}
Some foo text with \faGoogle
\end{document}
```

**Update** with `Futura-Normal` font and using `XeLaTeX`. The colour definitions are taken from [Google new logo](http://designpieces.com/palette/google-new-logo-2015-color-palette-hex-and-rgb/), the font is `Product Sans`, but this font isn't free, therefore I choose `Futura-Normal` (http://allfont.net/download/futura-normal/)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\definecolor{GoogleGreen}{RGB}{60, 186, 84}
\definecolor{GoogleYellow}{RGB}{244, 194, 13}
\definecolor{GoogleBlue}{RGB}{72, 133, 237}
\definecolor{GoogleRed}{RGB}{219, 50, 54}
\newcommand{\GoogleLogo}{{\setmainfont{futura-Normal}\textcolor{GoogleBlue}{G}\textcolor{GoogleRed}{o}\textcolor{GoogleYellow}{o}\textcolor{GoogleBlue}{g}\textcolor{GoogleGreen}{l}\textcolor{GoogleRed}{e}}}

\begin{document}
\huge \GoogleLogo

Some foo text with 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: More of the entire "Google" logo

Comment: @RichardDuckman: See the update please

Comment: Thats great thanks! Needed a little tilt for the 'e' but apart for that works nicely!

Comment: @RichardDuckman: Yes, I know, the Futura Font isn't precisely what Product Sans gives, but as said: That font isn't free for open source :-(

Comment: For anyone interested, I managed to find the Product Sans at http://www.xamphyx.com/product-sans-download.html - and then for the final result with the angle of the 'e' add \textcolor{GoogleGreen}{l}\hspace{-1pt}\textcolor{GoogleRed}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{20.5}{e}}}} . @Christian Hupfer: Thanks for all the help, you're a star!

Comment: @RichardDuckman: Well, as I said, the Product Sans is **not** free -- Don't refer to me if you get into legal troubles ;-)

Answer (score 7):

My answer at [create latex symbol from vector graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224357/create-latex-symbol-from-vector-graphics/224359#224359) does this (with the old Google logo).  I have updated the logo here to the one referenced by David (https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png), and adjusted the parameters slightly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\theirlogo{%
  \scalerel*{\includegraphics{googlelogo_color_272x92dp}}{X\rule[-.55ex]{0pt}{1pt}}}
\begin{document}
\Huge Google \theirlogo{}

\normalsize Can I insert my \theirlogo{} inline?

\tiny Can I insert my \theirlogo{} inline?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another text-based fake logo. Not perfect, but nearly...

[image: mwe]

Note: Compiled win `xelatex`. The `.ttf` are open source fonts available in [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % just to valign the .png 

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\definecolor{B}{HTML}{4285F4}
\definecolor{R}{HTML}{EA4335}
\definecolor{Y}{HTML}{FBBC05}
\definecolor{G}{HTML}{34A853}

\newcommand{\Google}{%
\textcolor{B}{\setmainfont{Poppins-Medium} G}%
{\setmainfont{JosefinSans-Bold}%
\textcolor{R}{o}%
\textcolor{Y}{o}%
\textcolor{B}{g}%
\textcolor{G}{l}%
\textcolor{R}{e}}}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\tiny Fake \Google\ logo\par
\normalsize Fake \Google\ logo\par
\Large Fake \Google\ logo\par
\Huge Fake \Google\ logo\par
\bigskip\hrule\bigskip
\normalsize Real \verb|.png| logo: 
\includegraphics[valign=c,height=2.5ex]{Escritorio/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png}  
\end{document}
```