# Elder Sign Symbol in Latex

Tags: symbols, packages

Does there exist a package that has Cthulhu Mythos's Elder Sign image, or a reasonable facsimile thereof?

[image: elder sign]

I've been using the *stave* package, but its just not the same

Comment: The package `graphicx` allows you to include images such this via the command `\includegraphics[<options>]{imagefile}`.

Comment: I suggest using Inkscape to trace the image in question and obtain a vectorized version that you can include using `\includegraphics`. See [Creating logo with fancy font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145227/5764).

Comment: Did you peruse the [Wikipedia article on the Elder Sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elder_Sign)? There are several, rather different-looking, symbols out there that can be called an Elder Sign.

Comment: @jon I was hoping for something that can be placed in-line and scales with the text, not just an image.

Comment: See, for example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/292652 on using an image scaled to the size of the text.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29402/how-do-i-make-my-document-look-like-it-was-written-by-a-cthulhu-worshipping-madm?s=1|29.7525