# Screaming ghost symbol in tex

Tags: graphics, packages, svg

I recently came across this screaming ghost graphic in the book of "The Elements of  Statistical Learning". I searched for tex packages for this but could not find one. Are there any packages which already contain this?

[image]

Comment: You can make your own, given an image.  See, for example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175443/how-to-use-a-custom-scalable-symbol-in-latex, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270351/a-ruler-symbol-in-latex, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554460/scale-own-math-symbol-image-appropriately, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292638/writing-google-logo-in-latex

Comment: That’s from “The Scream,” by Edvard Munch. If it looks like a ghost to you, that’s a valid interpretation.

Comment: @Davislor : Yes I am aware of it! My use of the adjective "screaming" probably comes from there.

Comment: Great. Should not be hard to find a thumbnail, then. If you can convert to a scalable format that won’t pixelate, even better.

Comment: @Davislor : Seems like that's the only option. I thought this could be already in a package that I am possibly not aware of. Let us see if someone knows any relevant package.

Comment: https://openclipart.org/detail/249738/scream (and https://openclipart.org/detail/219603/the-scream and https://openclipart.org/detail/320833/the-scream-1895-by-edvard-munch)

Comment: @Thérèse Good finds! I think the best approach, technically, would be to download and crop the SVG version of [your third link,](https://openclipart.org/detail/320833/the-scream-1895-by-edvard-munch) then [include the SVG in your document.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/how-to-include-svg-diagrams-in-latex) That said, pixelation on a thumbnail should not be noticeable.

Answer (score 2):

I’m not aware of any LaTeX package that has Edvard Munch’s “The Scream.”

However, LaTeX lets you include any picture you want, and that one is in the public domain.  The approach I would recommend would be to download the clip art as a SVG, such as [this one](https://openclipart.org/detail/320833/the-scream-1895-by-edvard-munch) Thérèse found, crop the part of it you want with a program like Inkscape, and [include the SVG graphic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/how-to-include-svg-diagrams-in-latex) in your document.

That will get you a vector graphic that doesn’t pixelate, but pixelation on a thumbnail would probably not be noticeable anyway.  So you can use your format of choice.