# Scaling figures to line height

Tags: graphics, fontsize, scaling

I am writing a document which describes the user interface of a software application. I want to use the actual icons as part of the description text (as in "Press XXX", where XXX is replaced by an actual icon).

How can I scale the icons so that they fits nicely within the text, without hardcoding a size? I can `\includegraphics[heigth=something]` but I would like this "something" to automatically adapt to changes in line height, font size, etc.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps the answers to this question, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224357/create-latex-symbol-from-vector-graphics, would serve as an answer.

Comment: height=1ex is the x height of the current font so height of lower case letters usually, or 1.2ex , or height=1em which is (usually) the nominal font size or height=\ht\strutbox which is the height of a strut (this should _just_ fit in the line without affecting baselinespace or ...