# Pencil symbol with xelatex (and unicode-math)

Tags: xetex, unicode-math

I don't know how to produce a command wich gives me a pencil symbol with xelatex (and unicode-math).

I would like a pencil such as the U+270E unicode caracter or a similar symbol.
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/270e/index.htm

Thank you for help.

EDIT : So how to get the pencil with CMU font ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[tuenc]{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{CMU Serif} %needed for me to get small-bold caps
    \setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
    \setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{unicode-math} %works without this

\begin{document}

%\symbol{"270E} doesnt' work ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: if U+270E isn' t in the font you are using can you not just include an image?

Comment: Perhaps `\faPencil` from the `fontawesome` package is a bypass?

Comment: Thank you but It would be easier to have a "true" font without loading another package if possible.

Comment: You can always download an online graphic and use a scaled `\includegraphics` approach as in, for example, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224357/create-latex-symbol-from-vector-graphics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The glyph is not in CMU Serif, but it's easy to get it from another font.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}

\newfontface{\pencilfont}{DejaVu Sans}[Scale=MatchUppercase]

\newunicodechar{✎}{{\pencilfont ✎}}

\begin{document}

Here's a pencil ✎ with text around it.

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also input `^^^^270e` instead of `✎`.

Note that `tuenc` is the default, with the most recent version of `fontspec`. Also `Ligatures=TeX` has long been the default (except for the monospaced font).

Comment: Thank you. It's excactly what I need.
So should I remove `tuenc` ? and `Ligatures=TeX` ?

Comment: @Oli With the current version of `fontspec`, yes, both.

Answer (score 2):

The fileformat site also include a list of fonts that support your character. So it is easy to get one with the symbol:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}

\begin{document}
a pencil \symbol{"270E}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But how to get the pencil with CMU font ?
(See EDITED first post).

Comment: You can't. If a font doesn't have a glyph then it isn't there. You will to switch to another font temporarly.