# Recognize this letter

Tags: fonts, symbols

Does anybody know how to make the following symbol in LaTeX? I think it is some calligraphic `\mathcal{E}`.

[image]

It is not anywhere in [this table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode) and online font recognizers do not recognize it.

The general font in the book I got this symbol from, *Introduction to Quantum Optics* by Grynberg, is not very extraordinary: this is a formula containing the strange symbol:

[image]

Comment: If you can't find it in a font, you can always import it as a graphic and adapt it via https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224357/create-latex-symbol-from-vector-graphics/224359#224359

Comment: Yes! Thats works, even in math mode.

Comment: A marginally close representation: (http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/frenchcursive/) via `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[default]{frcursive}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
E
\end{document}`

Comment: Where did it come from, and what does it mean?

Comment: @ChrisH, it comes from the book "Introduction to Quantum Optics" from Grynberg, page 314 for example. It represents something like the complex amplitude of one mode of the electric field.

Comment: I can't see that page online, but something similar to a normal `\mathcal{D}` is used in other notation in the book.  It doesn't seem to use any unusual fonts on pages I can preview.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, thank you for your help, but those do not remotely look like the symbol in my question.

Comment: I was guessing based on other letters from The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List (page 76).

Comment: Online font matching site suggests it is from `Typo Upright` font or `Linoscript` font

Comment: You can see the E of Linoscript here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eXUc.png In case you happen to have this font, you should be able to use it with xelatex or lualatex

Comment: @samcarter -- that's the beast.  you should post that as the answer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton done :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Online font matching sites suggests this symbol is from `Linoscript` font or  `Typo Upright` font. I think it is the former, as the spiral in the lower part of the E is a bit different.

In the following image you can see an example of `Linoscript` (from https://www.linotype.com/45918/linoscript-product.html):

[image]

And of `Typo Upright` (from https://www.linotype.com/1086717/typo-upright-regular-product.html)

[image]

In case you have this font installed on your computer, you can use `xelatex` or `lualatex` in order to use the symbol in your document.

Comment: Very nice sleuthing!

Answer (score 17):

It also looks very much like `TypoUpright BT` (originally designed by Morris Fuller Benton in  1905 as a reproduction of the 19th century *French Ronde*), which can be obtained freely from [myfontfree](http://www.myfontfree.com/typoupright-bt-myfontfreecom96f31037.htm).

Here is a demo with `xelatex`:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \newfontfamily{\uprightcal}{TypoUpright BT}

    \begin{document}%

    Some text.

    \Huge\uprightcal{E}

    \end{document}
```

[image]