# How to make this curly 'R' (ℛ)?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols

Which package has a similar looking fancy R or does anyone know how to make one? (Note: the line underneath the R is just the notebook paper... this is from a scanned set of notes).

[image]

Comment: Where you have seen this symbol? Thank you.

Comment: The closest I could find on the web is `Lauren Script ` font, but requires using `fontspec`.

Comment: @Bernard Hello very kind. In fact I don't see any correlation with the classic LaTeX fonts.

Comment: No, if you have to use it, it has to be imported. The simplest is via xelatex or lualatex + fontspec. Of course any font can be  adapted for use with LaTeX, but it takes quite some tome to do.

Comment: @user2154420...check this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/481251/120578

Comment: I really don't think the edits to my question were helpful, nor will they help out future users. However, @koleygr's comment is very useful, and I'd gladly accept it as an answer.

Comment: @user2154420: My question/answer is possibly a wrong movement that should rather be avoided in this site because it doesn't work like this. The original question is yours and by knowing that I should not open a new question with the same request. I don't really know what a correct movement should be and didn't wanted to vote to reopen your question just to add my answer because if you search in this site there are many questions looking for specific symbols closed. I just tried to help and to make my effort on drawing this letter useful to you. When your question reopen wait for more answers.

Comment: @koleygr Hi, I have given my reopen :-). Best regards.

Comment: I suspect you might be thinking of the MathTime Pro curly script font.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My answer is by using tikz (but with simple lines and not `fill` to add effect of width):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{}
\newcommand{\fancyR}{\sbox1{\vbox{R}}\sbox2{\hbox{R}}\tikz[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]{\coordinate (A);\draw[-,black,line width=0.55pt,scale=0.75]([shift={({\the\wd2/2},0)}]A) to[out=180,in=0] ++(-{\the\wd2/2},{3*(\the\ht1+\the\dp1)/5)}) to[in=90,out=180]++({-\the\wd2/5},{-(\the\ht1+\the\dp1)/8})
to[in=270,out=270]++({\the\wd2/2},{7*(\the\ht1+\the\dp1)/12})
to[in=0,out=90]++(-{7*\the\wd2/20},{3*(\the\ht1+\the\dp1)/12})
to[in=90,out=180]++(-{13*\the\wd2/24},-{11*(\the\ht1+\the\dp1)/12})
to[in=180,out=270]++({3*\the\wd2/12},{-4*(\the\ht1+\the\dp1)/10})
to[in=270,out=0]++({11*\the\wd2/48},{(\the\ht1+\the\dp1)/3})
to[in=300,out=90]++(-{3*\the\wd2/13},{11*(\the\ht1+\the\dp1)/12})
to[in=40,out=120]++(-{6*\the\wd2/10},-{1*(\the\ht1+\the\dp1)/6});
}}
\begin{document}
$\mathbb{R}$R\fancyR{}$R$
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: See what happens when you do `{\Huge $\mathbb{R}$R\fancyR{}$R$}` and then consider using `line width=0.06em` instead. BTW, you could drop all of the `\sbox`, `\wd` and `\dp` stuff in favor of relative units, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480818/121799.  (And what is `\usetikzlibrary{}` good for?)

Comment: Thanks @marmot... I have already read that post. My idea was the relative height and width too, but didn't thought to use `em` or `ex` because I tried to use the actual R's lengths (I know this is not exactly working!). The answer was posted somehow faster than should and I forgot to use line width too in relation with my measured sizes. Of course I could have save the lengths too instead of retyping. I will edit soon. Thanks. (\tikzlibrary{} just left there and loads features about `nothing` :P )

Answer (score 13):

Here are two fancy R options:

[image]

You can consult **Table 307: Math Alphabets** on page 119 of [the comprehensive list](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) for other options.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{rsfso}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
$\mathscr{R}$ & \verb`$\mathscr{R}$` with \verb`mathrsfs` package\\
$\mathcal{R}$ & \verb`$\mathcal{R}$` with \verb`rsfso` package
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like mtpro2 curly font to me :-)

Comment: @user2154420: I posted my answer before koleygr's comment. Your question did not indicate any knowledge of standard sources such as the comprehensive list. If you don't find this answer helpful, fine. But please refrain from insulting me (or other users on this site). We are only trying to be helpful.

Comment: Your message came to me :-( Then I knew just afterwards. But then I read the previous comments that didn't refer to me. I'm not the type to insult or offend. My upvoted.

Comment: @sebastiano: that message was not for you. Your comments are always kind. The OP called me lazy in a comment that was since deleted. It was quite a surprise.

Comment: But let it go, stay calm and think about your health (what I don't do). I wish you well.  Greetings.

Comment: In fact, none of the alphabets in table 307 of the comprehensive lists contains an "R" with this shape.  The `mathpro2` curly font (as identified by @Sebastiano) is the closest that I know, but this font is commercial and must be paid for.  (And that is the reason it's not in the comprehensive list.)  The letter may also be in other commercial fonts that I'm not familiar with.  The graphicdesign.stackexchange site might be helpful in this respect.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Very wise. Thank you for the advice. Tanti auguri!

Comment: I think the name of the package for `\mathscr` is `mathrsfs`, not `mathsfrs`.

Comment: @Hypercube: Good catch! I'll make an edit.

Answer (score 10):

In the modern toolchain with `unicode-math`, you can set any TrueType or OpenType font as your script alphabet (or calligraphic, or a new alphabet).  For this example, I downloaded the OTF version of Odelette by Adi Marwah into a subdirectory of my project folder named `fonts`.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchUppercase}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[Path = ./fonts/, range = scr]{Odelette.otf}

\begin{document}
\[ \mathscr{R} \subset \mathscr{T} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: Odelette sample]

Comment: Upvoted you. :-). In fact to have the similar R we must go out the "classic" font LaTeX using font .ttf or otf.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks! The R from [Stardust Adventure](https://www.dafont.com/stardust-adventure.font?fpp=100&text=RECZQ) looks even more like the handwriting, but in my opinion Odelette looks pretty reasonable as a math alphabet. It comes down to personal taste.

Comment: I always vote positively efforts, what I'm trying to make understand to users of Physics.SE. If you are registered you will find a -5 :-) on my question. Rigid thinking makes me sad.

Comment: @Sebastiano I don’t believe I’m registered there, but I’ve been on SX communities where, if I tried to actually help a new user, I got flamed for making it harder to efficiently delete and remove “bad questions.” TeX.SX is much friendlier!

Comment: I agree with you at the 100%.

Comment: I've been shot. :-). I thought I was the only one who was shot. :-)

Answer (score 5):

I prefer this from (`mt2pro`) (the image is taken from this link https://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html):

[image: https://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[mtpccal]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
\[
\mathcal{R}
\]
\end{document}
```

If you prefer there is also this font TeX Gyre Pagella Math for the character bit curly R.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\newcommand{\nR}{\mathversion{Pagella} $\mathscr{R}$}
\setmathfont[version=Pagella]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\begin{document}
\nR
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to define the first R locally? I like it, but I also use the usual mathcal{R} in this document.

Comment: @user2154420 Unfortunately, the first R is a paid character, as the very good barbarian beeton has already written to you. There would be a chance and it works great but it's off-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

If you could obtain a higher-res image of it, or better still an image in vector format, then this approach would work for most situations.  However, it is impervious  to things like `\textit`, `\textcolor`, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\fancyR{\scalerel*{\includegraphics{fancyR}}{R}}
\begin{document}

$ab\fancyR c \scriptscriptstyle ab\fancyR c$

$ y = x^{\fancyR}$

$ab\fancyR c \quad\scriptscriptstyle ab\fancyR c$

$x_{\fancyR} = 0$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No Steven :-):-) is very ugly! Bleah :-(.

Comment: @Sebastiano It is ugly because the original provided by the OP was low resolution.  When provided in high resolution, or as a vector image, a much better result ensues: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224357/create-latex-symbol-from-vector-graphics/224359#224359

Comment: Yeah, I know. You don't have to justify yourself. I was just smiling as each of us tries to do everything possible to get the best for the user. I'm sorry he offended Sandy, however.

Comment: @Sebastiano No offense was taken.  I thought I detected your tongue in your cheek, but wasn't 100% sure.  You are right...as it stands, it is very ugly!

Comment: I did a test with online tools that vectorize a rasterized image. The result is very bad. The only solution, inserting an image, is that you have to use an external program either to make the image clean or create it again by hand, scan it and insert it.

Comment: @Sebastiano Correct.  I am not talking about vectorinzing a rastor image, but rather creating a vector master image, created with lines and arcs, rather than pixels.  That or a hi-def rastor image to start with.