# How to draw a curly R symbol if can't be found available in packages and available symbols

Tags: symbols

This is my answer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/481230/120578) question that is already closed (no problem if this will be closed too but had to upload my result to help the OP there since I had already draw it -or something like it-)

The Symbol was this:

[image]

Comment: Interesting strategy (I know you will get mad at me, but I cannot refrain from making this comment.): write a question, quickly add an answer and then close it such that no one else can write a shorter and/or more elegant answer. Just for the records: I do believe the same can be achieved in a much simpler fashion, also using a line width and distances specified in relative units.

Comment: @marmot ... I just tried to not leave the question opened (this would just ask for votes in my mind) and that if that question (that you also voted to be closed) is already closed... mine should be close too. I also thought that I don't really have to wait for editors to take the responsibility to close it if I could close it myself, and didn't found a reason to vote to reopen the other question since this would cause problems because of many such questions. Feel free to vote to reopen and add your elegant solution. (Not mad at all but confused about the right behavior and the way you think).

Comment: I voted to reopen (and also, thought that just the OP of that question will see it since marked immediately as a duplicate )

Comment: I am fine with the original question being closed. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480768/121799) is a (IMHO) great post with answers that discuss what you one can do. If you ask the question for this R you can ask questions for any letter and any style and will drown in posts. If you have something interesting to say, please consider adding it to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480768/121799.

Comment: I made that letter while people was voting to close that question. I know it is not perfect, I know that the idea is simple, I know that there are many questions like this, But since the OP could find it useful I had to give him the opportunity to use the code just for this letter and with no expectations on this. You just said that the question this is closed and you are fine with it. So, it would be wrong to vote to reopen and I agree. But you still think that I had to record in my "achievements" a duplicate and an answer with zero votes... for not letting people to add better solutions!

Comment: I think it would have been better to vote for reopen to that original post and adding that you want to answer ...

Comment: To reviewers: This post is not the original post and thus it has to be closed again when and if it will open. The original post is voted to reopen and this post will remain closed or will be closed again if opened. So, just vote to reopen the original post (if you was ready to vote for this one) that have been asked from another user and belongs to him as a question. For this one may be it is better to open just to not be left on the review list for months and somebody (possibly me again) will vote to close (or close it) as far as the original is open. Sorry about this.Tried for good... but...