# How to make these symbols typable in latex

Tags: symbols

There is a constructed language called "toki pona" and it has exactly 120 words. One of the scripts it has called "sitelen pona". And I need to use it for documents. Here is the all glyphs it has:
[image]

a symbol for every word.
Is there a way to use it without fonts?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you have a font, you can use it with XeLaTeX. There should be some answers in this forum about how to use fonts with XeLaTeX in general.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. How do you want to enter the symbols in your code? Do you want some kind of mapping from Latin/English letters to these symbols? Or you want to type commands like `\first \second` etc? Or you want to type it directly using a custom font?

Comment: you can cut that image (or a higher resolution one) in 120 single images and then create a macro to `\incluedrapghics` them by number, or name, or whatever mnemonic you have. Or if you're really *very* bored you can create each one of them with a small Ti*k*Z picture... ;-)

Comment: i want commands to type @Marijn

Comment: In that case you should indeed make 120 images and define 120 macros, for example `\def\akesi{\includegraphics{akesi}} \def\ala{\includegraphics{ala}}` etc for `akesi.png`, `ala.png` and so on. But using a font seems easier, there are fonts at https://github.com/toki-pona/ilo-pi-sitelen-pona/tree/master/client/styles/fonts/tp for example.

Comment: You can follow this approach: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224357/create-latex-symbol-from-vector-graphics/224359#224359.  But instead of using the graphic for a logo, use it for a symbol in your alphabet.