# How can I write this symbol resembling a little flame in latex?

Tags: symbols

I have encountered this symbol resembling a little flame (inside the norm inside the expectation) in a paper, does anyone know how to write it in latex? Here is the link to the paper:
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/jae.3950050202
its in page 105.
[image: Little flame]

Comment: I think it is a script small s, but the picture is too small to be able to recognize it.

Comment: Can you link to the paper where you found it?

Comment: Edited the link in the question.

Comment: The article is behind a paywall. Can you please insert an image with a better resolution? Don't worry about copyright, you're not breaking it.

Comment: Edited in a bigger snapshot.

Comment: I checked the paper, and yes, I agree it is a small script `s`.  It is defined as a generic element of a set denoted by capital script S.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To me, this small flame really just looks like a lowercase script S. I couldn't find a font that seemed to match exactly the picture, but the lowercase script S from Boondox seems rather similar.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage[scr=boondox]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
\(E[\lVert \,_\mathscr{s} \rVert^2]\)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

If you can't find the exact symbol as part of an existing math font, I recommend following the lead of this answer, [create latex symbol from vector graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224357/create-latex-symbol-from-vector-graphics/224359#224359), in which you use a downloaded icon as for your flame symbol.

For example, this icon: http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/aiq/6oa/aiq6oaq5T.png can be downloaded to `aiq6oaq5T.png` and made part of a macro `\mylogo`, which will automatically adjust its size to the current fontsize.  The flame is made the same height as an `X` of the current font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,amsmath}
\def\mylogo{\scalerel*{\includegraphics{aiq6oaq5T}}{X}}
\begin{document}
Can I insert my \mylogo{} inline?

{\tiny Can I insert my \mylogo{} inline?}

$E[\Vert \mylogo\Vert^2]$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the logo universally smaller, change the `X` in the `\mylogo` definition to a smaller footprint, such as `x`:

[image]