# How do I render (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻ and other exotic Unicode?

Tags: xetex, unicode, sharelatex

I want to insert a flipping tables and some Emoji in a LaTeX document on ShareLaTeX. I did some research, and came up with the following.

First of all, XeLaTeX needs to be used for best Unicode support and support for TTF fonts. Then a font needs to be used that contains the relevant Unicode symbols. And this font needs to be uploaded to ShareLaTeX.

For the font I selected DejaVu, known for its broad Unicode support.

For the Emoji I used the Noto Emoji font, and created a text command for that.

```
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setromanfont{DejaVuSerif.ttf}
\setsansfont{DejaVuSans.ttf}
\setmonofont{DejaVuSansMono.ttf}

\newfontfamily\emoji{NotoColorEmoji.ttf}

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textemoji}{\emoji}
```

Now I would like to be able to write something like

```
\title{foo \textemoji{} bar(╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻}
```

But the flip between the flipper and the table renders as a tofu and the Emoji renders as two wide tofu's.

[update] As @ShreevatsaR pointed out, DejaVu does not contain the vertical bracket, nor does NotoEmoji seem to contain the potato emoji. I have added the Symbola font and made another text command

```
\title{foo \textemoji{\char"1F360} bar \textsymbola{(╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻}}
```

This renders the flipping tables correctly but not the potato. Roasted Sweet potato does work, so it really comes down to finding a font that has it. It appears NotoColorEmoji does contain it, but that fails to load.

So the question boils down to: How can I render color fonts? Or alternatively: Is there a font XeLaTeX supports that contains U+1F360?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Rather than posting code snippets it is batter to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that, in particular, compiles. This make it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: There is no Emoji in “(╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻” as that sequence is entirely made up of characters from other Unicode blocks (such as Box Drawing) (unless you count the U+25A1 WHITE SQUARE from the Geometric Shapes block). Try pasting your sequence of characters [here](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/) to see for yourself. So I don't think NotoColorEmoji is a useful font to use in this context.

Comment: You can also look at the `.log` file that is generated: it will contain lines like `Missing character: There is no ︵ in font [DejaVuSerif]/OT…` which are helpful. (IMO the default settings when a character is missing should be for xelatex to just fail and show as loud a warning as possible, but instead such warnings are buried in the log file and doesn't even get output to terminal.)

Comment: LuaLaTeX also works, not just XeTeX.

Comment: I see your question about U+1F954 POTATO wasn't really answered. See [here](https://github.com/googlei18n/noto-emoji#using-notocoloremoji): “NotoColorEmoji uses the CBDT/CBLC color font format, which is supported by Android and Chrome/Chromium OS, but not MacOS.” Does this character work in other applications? XeTeX uses system libraries for fonts, so it may be hard to pick up this character. Good luck finding a font that contains it… the character was only added in Unicode 9.0 last year, so font support may not be great.

Comment: See also [this answer on this site by Khaled Hosny](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225732/48) for useful context. There are of course other ways to get coloured emoji: you can use a black-and-white font and colour that glyph in TeX ([example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59125/48)), or you can use something that puts tiny images at those positions instead of glyphs from a font. (Google search gives results like [this](https://github.com/alecjacobson/coloremoji.sty) and [this](https://github.com/doraTeX/coloremoji).)

Comment: 