# How to enter  in latex

Tags: xetex, symbols, unicode

I need to enter the  sign in LaTeX for a paper I'm writing. I tried compiling my paper using XeLaTeX, but it just ignores . Is there perhaps a way to enter the 's Unicode code point itself into LaTeX that I'm missing?

Comment: Does your font have this character? If not, you'll need to either create one yourself (with Tikz?) or find a font that has it.

Comment: I'm using the default Computer Modern

Comment: That font does not contain all of unicode, so you'll have to start by finding a font that provides this character

Comment: This particular character is only found in the Apple Color Emoji font, and this font doesn't encode characters as regular characters, so can't be used. See [Emoji Characters](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/88305).

Comment: Just for the record, this is U+1F171: NEGATIVE SQUARED LATIN CAPITAL LETTER B.

Comment: If the problem is literally how to enter it, because your editor’s font doesn’t display it, `\char{"1F171}` ought to work.

Comment: est of luck to you!

Comment: Does your paper happen to be about oneless izza?

Comment: “When you need to finish your paper but memes are life”

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Apple Color Emoji font that contains this particular character doesn't encode its glyphs as regular characters and can't be used. See [Emoji Characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88305). There seem to be very few fonts which contain these glyphs (the Enclosed Alphanumeric Supplement in Unicode).

On my machine (a Mac), only one font contains them: the Hiragino fonts.  Here's an example that works for me (compile with LuaLaTeX, not XeLaTeX, which didn't work for me.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newfontfamily\Hiragino{Hiragino Sans}[Color=red]
\begin{document}

{\Huge\Hiragino }
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Yeah, I think it just amounts to finding a font on your computer that has . On my computer (running Ubuntu), the font "Symbola" worked for me.

Comment: @BrianLee I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: @AlanMunn Kind and excellent user but the color of B symbol change always? Before It war brown, after red and now magenta.

Answer (score 15):

This  sign in LaTeX it can work also without `XeLaTeX`. It is an alternative.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\Boo}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
\node [fill=magenta, draw=magenta, rounded corners,minimum height = 12pt, minimum width = 12pt, inner sep = 1] at (10pt,10pt) {\textcolor{white}{\textbf B}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
We have \Boo{} a new symbol.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe too classic, but ...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{xcolor}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{}%
{{\fboxsep1pt\colorbox{black}{\color{white}\sffamily\bfseries B}}}
\newunicodechar{}%
{{\fboxsep1pt\colorbox{black}{\color{white}\sffamily\bfseries A}}}


\begin{document}

lck and white

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option with `tcbox`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newtcbox{\mychar}[1][]{nobeforeafter, tcbox raise base, colback=red, colframe=black, sharp corners, colupper=white, size=fbox, #1}

\begin{document}

How to write \mychar{B} or any other char (\mychar{A}, \mychar[colback=blue!70!black]{Z}, \mychar{!}, \mychar{\dots}) in \LaTeX

\end{document}
```

[image]