# Latex is not generating PDF due to emojis. How to have colourful emojis in PDF version?

Tags: latex3

Here is the sample code

```
   \begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}
   %!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
   %%BoundingBox: 19 19 221 221
   %%CreationDate: Mon Sep 29 1997
   %%Creator: programmed by hand (JK)
   %%EndComments
   gsave
   newpath
   20 20 moveto
   20 220 lineto
   220 220 lineto
   220 20 lineto
   closepath
   2 setlinewidth
   gsave
   .4 setgray fill
   grestore
   stroke
   grestore
   \end{filecontents*}
   %
   \RequirePackage{fix-cm}
   %
   %\documentclass{svjour3}                  % onecolumn (standard format)
   %\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}  % onecolumn (ditto)
   \documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}    % onecolumn (second format)
   %\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}       % twocolumn
   %
   \smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
   %
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{coloremoji}
   %
   % \usepackage{mathptmx}      % use Times fonts if available on your TeX 
   system
   %
   %\usepackage{latexsym}
   % \newcommand{}{}
   %
   % Insert the name of "your journal" with
   % \journalname{myjournal}
   %
   \begin{document}
   \begin{abstract}
   Insert your abstract here. Include keywords, PACS and mathematical
   subject classification numbers as needed.
   \keywords{First keyword \and Second keyword \and More}
   % \PACS{PACS code1 \and PACS code2 \and more}
   % \subclass{MSC code1 \and MSC code2 \and more}
   \end{abstract}

   \section{Introduction}
   \label{intro}
   Emoji
```

I want latex to generate colourful  in PDF. Also, I followed the following links to solve my problem:

```
  https://github.com/henningpohl/latex-emoji?files=1
  https://github.com/alecjacobson/coloremoji.sty
```

I cloned above packages in the same folder where my latex file is and included following in the latex code:

```
  \usepackage{coloremoji}
```

But this is generating error as:
      ! LaTeX Error: File `l3regex.sty' not found.

Comment: I think you are missing only `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: This package worked. Thanks. Do you know any package to include colourful emojis in latex pdf?

Comment: On emojis see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88305/emoji-characters

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.