# What type of packages are available to produce emoticons in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols, packages

I will need to use emoticons for a document that I am producing and I want to know which is the state-of-the-art in the available packages to produce emoticons in LaTeX?

So far, there is just some ad hoc references to some packages. A list of all available packages (or at least the most important ones) in a systematic way I think would be useful for users to have a organized source to choose the appropriate package according to their needs.

Comment: Do you want emoticons that are tiny graphics, or do you want something that constructs the more historical variety (as a collection of cleverly arranged ASCII symbols)? ;^)

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3695/27635 for example

Comment: And http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58901/27635

Comment: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzsymbols also provides some smileys.

Comment: @karlkoeller: useful, but I already had seen that examples, seems somehow incomplete in get the overall view of what type of packages are available.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes: If I get your question right I am looking for symbols to insert in text that look like tiny graphics, but if there are two different ways of do it probably the answer can have the two types.

Comment: There are some ways described in the linked questions. I suggest to close this as its duplicate.

Comment: @Johannes_B don't seem to me that answer my question. That post does not have a well organized state-of-the-art about the available packages. Just some Ad hoc references, in my humble opinion. That's why I arise the question.

Comment: Please edit the question and add some explanations why the (now duped) question is not duplicate. Please also explain, what you mean by *state of the art*.

Comment: By state of the art I mean the listing of all available packages (or at least the most important ones) in a systematic way. What I see is just ad hoc references of packages with emoticons.