# What font is this smiling sun character in?

Tags: symbols

I'm hoping this question is not too far off topic for this group. I created a logo for my wife's business that incorporated a smiling sun character. I now only have it as an image file, but I would like to use this character again. Unfortunately, I can no longer find the font that it is in. I have searched through all the fonts on my system and can't locate it. Can anyone tell me what font this character is in?
[image: logo with smiling sun]
<sub>(source: [healingscents.com](http://beta.healingscents.com/images/HSLogo.png))</sub>

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is indeed off topic here. Maybe you are luckier on [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This is probably a `real` graphics file and not a font in the sense of typography.

Comment: I created the logo in Gimp using a text font, not from a graphics file and then saved it as a graphics file.

Comment: @user56790: So you certainly remember the name of the text font? ;-) But as egreg already stated: Your question is not connected to TeX.SX as it does not refer to `TeX` at all and will be close most probably as off-topic.

Comment: Thank you, egreg, for pointing me toward Graphic Design. I see there are questions on font-identification there. Can this question be migrated over there?

Comment: Use `\HappySun` adding this in the preamble: `\usepackage{wasysym,xcolor,xspace}
\def\HappySun{\rlap{\makebox[1em][c]{\color{yellow!50!orange}\Large\sun}}\makebox[1em][c]{\raisebox{.17em}{\color{orange!50!red}\smiley}}\xspace}`

Comment: I guess it's time for me to learn Tex, so I can use that code, Fran!

Comment: @Fran Should I reword the question to ask how to code the happy sun? Then, if the question is taken off hold, you could make that comment an answer.

Comment: @user56790 No problem. Another option is draw a smiling sun with  Tikz. See also  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58901/something-between-frownie-and-smiley and  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3695/smileys-in-latex