# How to set font for emoji

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec

As discussed in [How to use Noto Color Emoji with lualatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/497403), in the dev version of lualatex one can use color emoji directly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Apple Color Emoji}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]
\begin{document}
Text  emoji 
\end{document}
```

But the normal latin letters are not displayed:

[image: img]

Is it possible to *automatically* select the font for emoji without changing the normal text font, just like `luatexja`/`xeCJK` for CJK ideographs?

Comment: LuaTeX combo fonts

Comment: you can define a fallback as described here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/572220/2388

Answer (score 3):

If you, one day, would like to use `pdfLaTeX` or with the engine `lualatex` there is a new recent package (April 2021) named `twemojis`. Here there is an example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{twemojis}
\begin{document}
Text {\twemoji{grinning cat}} emoji {\twemoji{tongue}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need font which has letters you need.

I didn't had `Apple Color Emoji` font so I used `symbola`.

[image: emojis]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Libration Sans}
\newfontfamily{\emojifont}{Apple Color Emoji}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]
\begin{document}
Text {\emojifont } emoji {\emojifont }
\end{document}
```