# How to substitute a glyph for a single Greek character?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, greek

I am using Minion Pro (with fontspec under LuaLaTeX), and the character `ϱ`(= \varrho, but in text mode) doesn't show.

```
input: ϱυϑμὸν
output: �υϑμὸν
```

Is there a way to globally remap only this character to a different font? I can, of course, use a different font for every instance (or all Greek text, for that matter) but would rather not.

Comment: you can setup a fallback font, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/572220/2388

Comment: Thanks. I'm not having trouble with emojis, but the principle should be the same. I'll give it a shot tonight.

Comment: I do know that emoiji and greek symbols are something different ;-). But yes the principle is the same.

Comment: Probably you want to substitute it with a standard rho, don't you?

Comment: @egreg: Not necessarily. If there is ϱ in the original text, I'd like to find a font that can display it. For a single character (and a rare one at that), pretty much any humanist font will do in a pinch.

Comment: @Ingmar The original text has a rho, the graphical realization of which depends on the printer/typographer or copyist.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thank you for pointing me to the fallback font option. Even though I ended up using `newunicodechar` in this case, this is a valuable option to have.

Comment: @egreg: I know, but not exactly being a Greek scholar myself this is a copy & paste & it should work kind of deal. The original used ϱ, so who am I to go change it to ρ instead? I saw your answer (since deleted) and incorporated it into mine, so thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering my own question, as it allows me more formatting than a simple comment, and to sum up the various answers and comments I have received. I have since discovered that my font is missing another character, `ɔ`, so my solution deals with both of them:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{MinionPro.otf}   % Any defective font will do. Font files kept in the 
                              % current directory to eliminate all path issues etc.
% The fallback font:
\newfontfamily{\gentium}[Scale=MatchLowercase]{GentiumPlus-Regular.ttf}

% (Only) if character is not found in current font, fall back to Gentium:
\newunicodechar{ϱ}{\iffontchar\font`ϱ ϱ\else{{\gentium ϱ}}\fi}
\newunicodechar{ɔ}{\iffontchar\font`ɔ ɔ\else{{\gentium ɔ}}\fi}

\begin{document}
{\huge Hellɔ woϱld!}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Might be worthwhile to load `gentium` with `Scale=MatchLowercase` so the glyphs are the same size. An `\ifmmode` would additionally let you use the symbols in math mode.

Comment: Duly noted. That said, I do quite a bit more than that, actually (loading font variants, providing for small caps features, ligatures and the like) but didn't consider it necessary for a minimal example. And I never need math mode: but since these answers seemingly live on forever, this is definitely an important point to consider for some.

Comment: Fair enough! Good self-answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have Minion Pro to test this, but you can set the character active with `newunicodechar`, look up whether the current font contains `ϱ` with `\iffontchar`, and return the character if so, e.g.

```
\iffontchar\font`ϱ\symbol"03F1\else\symbol"03C1\fi
```

In practice, you might want to wrap this further in `\ifmmode` to use `\varrho` in math mode, e.g.

```
\ifmmode%
  \varrho%
\else%
  \iffontchar\font`ϱ%
    \symbol"03F1%
  \else\symbol"03C1%
  \fi%
\fi
```

You hit on using Gentium as a fallback font, instead of ρ as a fallback glyph, which is a great idea.  You might want to load the supplemental font with `Scale=MatchLowercase` so the letters come out the same size.  Also be sure to enclose the font change in a group, so it does not bleed through to the following text.

```
\newfontfamily\gentium{Gentium}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\newunicodechar{^^^^03f1}{%
  \ifmmode%
    \varrho%
  \else%
    \iffontchar\font`ϱ%
      \symbol"03F1%
    \else{{\gentium\symbol"03F1}}%
    \fi%
  \fi}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Ultimately it was much easier:

`\newfontfamily{\gentium}{Gentium}` `\newunicodechar{ϱ}{\gentium ϱ}`

is all it took.

Comment: @Ingmar You at least want an extra pair of braces, `\newunicodechar{ϱ}{{\gentium ϱ}}`, or the font will stay switched to Gentium afterward.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!