# Missing character - setmainfont and alternative

Tags: fontspec

We use as main font `Liberation Sans` which misses many of the unicode characters. As far as I understand `DejaVu Sans` has many of them. Is there a way to automagical (!) switch the font in case `lualatex` complains about a missing character?

```
{/usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
Missing character: There is no ☎ (U+260E) in font LiberationSans:mode=node;scr
ipt=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;!
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[shorthands=off,bidi=basic]{babel}
\setmainfont{Liberation Sans}
%\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}

\begin{document}
Kontakt: ☎️ 
\end{document}
```

So the main idea is to define a *fallback* when the default misses the character. If the fallback doesn't have the character than that's fine. But at least one level would be great.

Using: `LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0`

Comment: see the luaotfload documentation, or e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/572220/2388

Comment: I posted a working sample as answer. Although I've copied the code from the docu I'm highly unclear why I need `script=grek`. Could you add a hint in the answer (as well as in the docu)? Thx.

Comment: you don't need script=grek, it is optional (in case you want to force a script).

Comment: Sorry, if I'm persistent. But why is it than mentioned in docu? (As sample `fallback`)

Answer (score 4):

Thx to Ulrike I found the following working sample

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{luaotfload.add_fallback
("emojifallback",
    { "DejaVu Sans:mode=harf;script=grek",
     "NotoColorEmoji:mode=harf"}
)}

\setmainfont{Liberation Sans}[RawFeature={fallback=emojifallback}]

\begin{document}
Kontakt: ☎️ »  
\end{document}
```

The `luaotfload` is automatically loaded with luaHBTeX. I have copied the sample from the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a particular character active, which lets you specify what font you want each individual symbol to come from, and also works in XeTeX or PDFTeX.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,english]{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[shorthands=off,bidi=basic]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmainfont{Liberation Sans}

\newfontfamily\emojifont{Noto Color Emoji}[
  Scale=MatchUppercase,
  Renderer=HarfBuzz ]

\newunicodechar{^^^^260e}{{\emojifont\symbol{"260E}}} % ☎️ 

\begin{document}
Kontakt: ☎️ 
\end{document}
```

[image: Noto Color Emoji sample]

Comment: Yeah, it meets my request but makes also clear that wording is sometimes tricky ;-) I have seen this approach already but have the major problem that I have to know the characters in advance. And when you cannot limit the input (e.g. since you auto generate tex) its getting tricky.

Comment: @LeO In XeTeX, the `ucharclasses` package lets you do it for entire Unicode blocks.