# How can I get babel to use a fallback font when a special character is missing from the main font?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, babel, directlua

Sometimes there is a character in my text that is not in the main font, such as Chinese characters or emojis, etc. and I do not want to constantly modify this in the text with various commands to change the font.

I know this can be done by changing the language, but I want LuaLateX itself to check a font list and use the character from theses fonts, when a character is not available in the main font.

This idea came to me when I saw this answer about using emojis in text:
[Substituting fonts for emojis in LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/572220/269074)

Is it possible to use such an algorithm for LuaLaTeX and babel package with directlua?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, main]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}
%%how force latex to use another font if an special charchter is not in Amiri font?
\begin{document}
  سلام\\
  hello\\
    \\
  你好
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just extend the provided fallback to more than one font and pass it normally.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, main]{arabic}

\directlua {
  luaotfload.add_fallback("myfallback", {
    "Noto Sans CJK SC:mode=harf;",
    "Noto Color Emoji:mode=harf;",
  })
}

\babelfont{rm}[RawFeature={fallback=myfallback}]{Amiri}

\begin{document}
سلام\\
hello\\
  \\
你好
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes it worked. thank you so much!