# Is there any way to retrieve saved string in the beginning of document from its end in LuaLaTeX?

Tags: luatex, unicode, strings, lua, registers

There are different types of “registers” in LuaTeX. With `totcount` package, you can save counter (number) from any place in a document and get its value also in any place in a document with the help of `.aux` file (maybe other extension). But is there any way to use this exact (or similar) feature with (Unicode) strings (in Lua)?

For example, I have calculated something at the end which shouldn't be precalculated (i. g., in the preamble) because that will make a big mess and will be much less readable. And then I need to use this result at the beginning (like a `\hyperref` of some sort, but just for string values). And of course this should be possible with multiple strings at the same time.

Comment: see how table of contents are implemented, write to a file, or the aux file and then read at begin document on the next run

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you for the advice. I was just hoping that there is already some sort of implementation for that in Lua(La)TeX.

Comment: it's a standard feature of latex,  at the end `\immediate\write\@auxout{\gdef\noexpand\wibble{my string]}` then on the next run `\wibble` will be defined from begin document to be `my string`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668852/is-there-any-way-to-retrieve-saved-string-in-the-beginning-of-document-from-its/668877#comment1662679_668852), I made an extensive example of what I wanted to achieve:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\lua[1]{\directlua{#1}}

\usepackage{fontspec}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572212/
% substituting-fonts-for-emojis-in-lualatex/572220#comment1662059_572220
\lua{luaotfload.add_fallback("FallbackFonts", {
  "Noto Color Emoji:mode=harf",
  "Noto Sans CJK JP:"
})}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}[RawFeature={fallback=FallbackFonts}]

% Get (command if defined)
\newcommand\Get[1]{\csname #1\endcsname}

% Lua get (if variable is not defined or
% argument is empty then nothing will be printed)
\newcommand\LGet[1]{\lua{tex.print(#1)}}

\makeatletter
% Global definition
\newcommand\Gdef[2]{\immediate\write\@auxout{%
  \unexpanded{\expandafter\gdef\csname #1\endcsname{#2}}%
}}

% Global Lua definition
\newcommand\GLdef[2]{\immediate\write\@auxout{%
  \unexpanded{\lua{#1 = #2}}%
}}

% Global Lua string definition
\newcommand\GLsdef[2]{\immediate\write\@auxout{%
  \unexpanded{\lua{#1 = "#2"}}%
}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

After 2nd run we get:

\Get{super@ cool!!}

\setlength\parskip{1ex}

\ifdefined\simplename
  \simplename
\fi

\LGet{this1}

\LGet{that2}

% Added nil check
\LGet{complex and complex.foo}

\LGet{complex and complex.bar}

% Later in document...

\GLdef{this1}{69}

\GLsdef{that2}{my Unicode string. やった！}

\GLdef{complex}{{foo = 123, bar = "string"}}

\Gdef{super@ cool!!}{%
  Any string that I want
  asdf
  asdfasd
  fasdfas

  df asdf
  as df \\
  sdf
   asf a sdfs
}

\Gdef{simplename}{Can be used without the use of additional command. But will
give an error if not checked for definition (during the 1st run).}
\end{document}
```

Which will create PDF (with `lualatex`) after 1st run:

[image: nothing]

And after 2nd run we get:

[image: everything]