# Emojis with lualatex

Tags: unicode, minted, emoji

I'm trying to use both the `lualatex` or `xelatex` commands to produce my document:

```bash
xelatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder "book.tex"
```

or

```bash
lualatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder "book.tex"
```

I was under the impression that `lualatex` and `xelatex` support emojis "out of the box", however, I'm getting the following errors like these:

```
Missing character: There is no ✔ (U+2714) in font [lmmono10-regular]:!
Missing character: There is no  (U+1F680) in font [lmmono10-regular]:!
Missing character: There is no  (U+1F4C4) in font [lmmono10-regular]:!
```

Most of the emojis appear in code snippets I have in my document, which look like this:

```latex
\begin{codeInput}{bash}{terminal}{Output of running the Android release lane.}
[✔]  
+----------------------------------------+---------+------------------------+
|                               Used plugins                                |
+----------------------------------------+---------+------------------------+
| Plugin                                 | Version | Action                 |
+----------------------------------------+---------+------------------------+
| fastlane-plugin-increment_version_cod  | 0.4.3   | increment_version_code |
| e                                      |         |                        |
+----------------------------------------+---------+------------------------+

[08:45:45]: Driving the lane 'android release' 
[08:45:45]: ------------------------------------
[08:45:45]: --- Step: increment_version_code ---
[08:45:45]: ------------------------------------
[08:45:45]: The increment_version_code plugin will use gradle file at (android/app/build.gradle)!
[08:45:45]:  -> line: (        versionCode 3
)!
[08:45:45]: ☝️ Version code has been changed to 4
\end{codeInput}
```

Here, `codeInput` is a custom `tcolorbox` with `minted` that I've created.

The PDF is indeed generated, but the emojis in the code snippets are simply missing:

[image: PDF generated code snippet]

Does anyone know how to get the emojis in my minted code snippets to work? I would guess it has something to do with adding emoji support to that specific font `lmmono10-regular`? Or passing some flags to `minted` perhaps?

I currently don't explicitely call `\setmainfont` in my document, if that helps.

Comment: You should switch to a font which has emoji.

Comment: you just need a font with emoji (not latin modern)

Comment: in lualatex you can setup a fallback font: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/572220/2388

Answer (score 5):

As Ulrike and David guided, it was indeed due to not having a font that supported emojis. Since for now the emojis are only found in my code snippets in my document, I only needed to change my monospace font settings. I borrowed the `\directlua` method from [Ulrike's earlier answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/572220/241538) and ended up using the following:

```latex
\usepackage{fontspec}

\directlua{luaotfload.add_fallback
   ("emojifallback",
    {
      "AppleColorEmoji:mode=harf;"
    }
   )}

\setmonofont{Fira Code}[
  RawFeature={fallback=emojifallback}
]
```

and make sure you compile your document using `lualatex`.

Emojis will work in your `minted` code snippets whether you write the source code directly in the LaTeX document or use `minted`'s ability to import the code from a file.