# Noto Color Emoji Lualatex

Tags: luatex, noto

I use Lualatex and the package emoji.
But I noticed that the emojis are not as "nice" as I expected.

For instance, the command `\emoji{joy}` gives me [image]
instead of   [image].

So I made some research and I found this post: [How to use Noto Color Emoji with lualatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497403/how-to-use-noto-color-emoji-with-lualatex)

I downloaded the file on this [web page](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Color+Emoji) and with a right click installed the font NotoColorEmoji-Regular (which is true type).
But with this MWE (found on the post I mentionned above):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Color Emoji}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]
\begin{document}
    
    
\end{document}
```

my document is blank and in the log file I have these kinds of lines:
Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "NotoColorEmoji/BI" (it probably
(fontspec)             doesn't exist).

So, I guess the font is not correctly installed (It appears in Word, though).
So how can I install the Noto Color Emoji font?

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of NotoColorEmoji is available as COLRv1 font which is a format that's not currently supported in LuaLaTeX. You can download the CBDT version instead:

Go to https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji/tree/main/fonts and select one of the files starting with NotoColorEmoji. Then download the file and install it as a system font.

Comment: Thank you@Marcel Krüger. It doesn’t matter which file I choose?

Comment: It shouldn't matter much, but the files are a bit different. Usually you should just take the normal `NotoColorEmoji.ttf`. If you for some reason are sure that you do not want flags and want smaller files you can also use the `-noflags` version. `emojicompat` is [specific for Android apps](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/text-and-emoji/emoji-compat) and there's little reason to use it otherwise, but I don't think that it would break. I would recommend to avoid the WindowsCompatible version unless really needed.

Comment: I downloaded `NotoColorEmoji.ttf` but I when I right clik on it and install it, I get the error message: doesn't seem to be a valid font

Comment: I found a Twemoji Mozilla.ttf and it works with it

Comment: In fact, it works with Twemoji Mozilla but emojis are less nice (no transparency, for instance). I don’t understand why I can’t make it work with Noto Color Emoji

Comment: Did you try the `WindowsCompatible` version?

Comment: I tried with `WindowsCompatible` and it works. Thanks a lot