# Vectorizable figures that can be editable outside latex

Tags: graphics, diagrams

Is there a package that while allows us to draw a vectorizable item (like a graph or a drawing) through latex, can also export it to a format editable by other tools? (Like ink-scape, Dia, etc... ).

It would be nice to have something drawn in latex and edit it in another program or vice versa.

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand your question correctly or not, but anyway: Ti*k*z (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) is a great tool for vector graphics. Inkscape can import `.pdf`-files. There is also an extension for Inkscape to export code for Ti*k*z, compare https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151232/exporting-from-inkscape-to-latex-via-tikz.

Comment: @CampanIgnis Maybe this will clarify better: Can the tikz package export the art to editable formats that other tools can handle? Most modern vector tools support multiple formats so I think even if tikz or any other package saves to a specific *editable* format, we're good.

Comment: @Anna K. I am not sure. There might be some scripts which turn Ti*k*z to `.svg`. The simplest way which I am currently aware of is using the http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone class to produce a `.pdf` and then import with Inkscape. That `.pdf` is editable. But someone else around here might know better.  Probably http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pstricks-base is more useful since PS is Turing-complete. I started with *PSTricks* but fully migrated to Ti*k*z and haven not used *PSTricks* for years.

Comment: The best way I can imagine is to learn tikz... It is a really strong package... When you need any complex shape you can export it from inkscape and use it in your code (it needs scaling and coloring from the start... but you can do some good job)... Check what I have done this way: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3695/smileys-in-latex/375029#375029 It is not something very special... but using code is one of more editable ways... I know you are looking something more... but I had to say that with tikz coding you can do much