# Telegram emoticon on LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there some package who implement all the telegram emoticon on LaTeX? I just want the possibility to implement the telegram emoticon not similar one. Like when all of us have used for years on whatsapp/facebook/telegram.

[image]

Comment: Are you aware of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3695/smileys-in-latex/227226)?

Comment: Not exacly what I'm looking for.  

marmot  Cragfelt

Comment: So you are looking for the colored versions of emojis?

Comment: Are you aware of the `tikzsymbols` package? It provides some pseudo-3D emoticons such as `\dSmiley`, see `texdoc tikzsymbols`.

Comment: In ConTeXt you can use Emojies directly (see these slides: http://www.gust.org.pl/bachotex/2017-pl/presentations/hhagen-thoekwater-1-2017.pdf)