# How to insert an angry emoticon in a sentence

Tags: symbols, packages

I would like to include an angry emoticon in a sentence, in my LaTeX document. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK to compile your document using `lualatex`, you could add the package [emoji](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/emoji). There are also [other answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3695/smileys-in-latex) to the similar question.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{emoji}

\begin{document}
\emoji{angry-face} Angry face!
\end{document}
```