# How can I render a spoon emoji (e.g. U+1F944)?

Tags: luatex, emoji

I'm referring to [this icon](https://emojipedia.org/spoon/): .

Can I render it in `LaTeX`?

Solutions other than via emoji are also accepted. The [`tikzsymbol` package](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzsymbols/tikzsymbols.pdf), though, which I've discovered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/227226/87996), doesn't seem to have a spoon. And for now I'm a bit lazy to draw my own spoon with Ti*k*Z.

Answer (score 3):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{twemojis}
\begin{document}
\twemoji{spoon}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Segoe UI Emoji is installed in Windows. You can also use other emoji fonts.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
{\fontspec{Segoe UI Emoji}\symbol{"1F944}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cookingsymbols}
\begin{document}
\Spoon
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}
\rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{\textcolor{lightgray}{\faSpoon}}
\end{document}
```

[image]